# Live: Left nav, new theming and responsiveness

Tags: discussion, navigation, responsive-design

> This post is now locked due to a lot of off-topic or very tangentially related issues being posted here. It's so large that it is pretty hard to find/triage issues listed. If you have a concern related to left nav, theming and/or responsiveness, then I'd encourage you to post them as a question on MSE or on the meta of the specific site you're concerned with.

We have released left navigation bar, our new theming and a our initial responsive design work on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange (it's been live on MSO for a week). This work has been in progress and being discussed with the community for several months. The motivation for the work is covered in my post entitled [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes), so check that out if you have any questions about why this work is important.

### Left nav and theming

Check out the new left navigation and new theme (most relevant to MSE). This work creates greater experience consistency across the Q&A sites and will increase in the velocity of bug fixes, improvements and new features to all sites thanks to a fully unified code base.

Based on early feedback from our initial announcement we've added a preference to unpin the left nav so it doesn't take up space. Just head on down to [your local preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) and check the box.

---

[image: Navigation preferences]

---

This is the biggest changes we made based on early feedback from the community. Check out the full list here: [Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps)

### Responsive design

Many of the most used pages on the site are now responsive to your window size. This benefits people who have lower resolution devices or like to have multiple windows in view. This functionality has been live for a few weeks for Stack Overflow for Teams users.

**This is a work in progress** and this step is a part of our effort to validate our significant changes to page layout code. Not all pages are responsive yet, asking a question and many moderator or review activities will not work in a smaller viewport and you'll need to expand the window. We are making improvements to this experience week by week, so it will just keep getting better.

We haven't fully optimized this for mobile devices, but click the "full site" option in the footer and you will get the responsive design on your phone. If for some reason you need access to the non-responsive version, we have a temporary feature for turning that on. Just click "Disable Responsive" option in the footer. This is a temporary feature that will go away once all the pages/features have been made responsive. The mobile optimized view will also remain in place until we finish making all the changes.

You can read more about the ins and outs in [Responsive design is enabled for Teams users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367724/responsive-design-is-enabled-for-teams-users).

### When is this coming to other sites?

After we gather feedback via this sneak peek on MSO/MSE we will be releasing this on other sites. Currently the plan is as follows:

- Mid-June:

  - ✅ release to SO and MSE
  - ✅ post update on fonts and theming: 
    [Fonts and the new Q&A theming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311033/fonts-and-the-new-qa-theming)
- July: release to network sites with "stock" theme and 5-10 other sites
- August - September: release to the remaining sites. As we have more details we will update individual communities in their local meta.

### Feedback

If you encounter a bug or a usability problem feel free to post it on MSE. We are eager to make updates so that this rollout goes smoothly for all communities.

Comment: Comments [archived](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1200/discussion-on-question-by-joe-friend-check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-t). Please post bugs / concerns as answers so that they can be tracked and addressed.

Comment: The new layout feels like facebook. I don't wanna be on facebook :/

Comment: Is there a reason the preference to hide it doesn't apply network-wide

Comment: Preference option doesn't work. Have to block the bar at the DOM level

Comment: @james Looking into why the pref isn't working for some.

Comment: I don't like new layout.

Comment: The pagewidth-fit is broken and objects that should be side-by-side are stacked vertically. I want to change the options but I'm directed to SO because "it's not live on MSE yet" but clearly this is false because I'm having to deal with it on MSE right now.

Comment: @nij Not sure what your comment is about. Please post an answer with images and more details.

Comment: @kevinb Yes. There are no cross-site preferences currently. Adding infra to support it is real work. I believe this is work we should do, but the case for it has been dubious in the past. Maybe this is the tipping point?

Comment: This menu makes me almost physically uncomfortable. Like walking around in wet shoes. Thanks for providing the setting to disable it.

Comment: For the next April 1st make sidebar take 50% of the screen and disable ability to hide it, please.

Comment: Any way to print a SO Q+A to PDF with a sensibly sized text layout, no waste of space (i.e. not 50% width wasted), and readable? I liked to be able to "archive" questions of interest for several reason a) printing out to paper at a later date, for b) reading offline purposes c) archiving in case questions were removed/fiddled with by "editors".....I guess I can't do that any more....it was getting tougher to see Q+As on a page over time already in a nice print readable format, without the side-bars getting in the way, ruining the layout.

Comment: One comment on the new UI:  The old one wasn't broken.

Comment: @ColinSmith Please delete your comment and add it as an answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Color me displeased at having "Public" shoved in my face.

Comment: I despise this new design. Questions and answers now get only about half the available browser window real-estate with the way I use my browser.

Comment: Thank God you can hide the left-nav. At least you remembered the most important rule in software development "*A new feature is a BUG if it cannot be TURNED OFF*".

Comment: @jthill Care to elaborate? You seem offended by the word "public" for some reason.

Comment: Came here to complain about the sidebar pushing the page to the right, learned that not only can you turn off the sidebar but you can also unpin the top menu! :D

Comment: FB like desing to get more empty space to populate more and more ads and more revenue until the new compititor doesn't make it's entry.

Comment: NO, the previous navbar (top one) was better. It had right amount of breathing space, usability and didn't take much of space too. This left navbar simply takes up quite unnecessary space (blank space when we scroll down) in the page. 
Also, with just 5 items in the menu, top navbar is a better choice than side navbar.
And if a side navbar is unavoidable then give a toggle button (hamburger button type) to close the navbar when not needed.

Comment: Agree with others. The new left nav looks cluttery. I dont need to navigate to 'Users' or 'tags' that often and I can imagine the same for most. In this already-complex world, simple interfaces are the way to go.

Comment: OK. How many people really think this looks nice and its helpful. Also thanks for the disable option for this side nav.

Comment: Add me to the sad pile - while I hid the new left pane, Im actually just left now with a lot of empty space.. making it seem odd

Comment: The page breaks aren't responsive - before the change, the questions "floated" when you increased the width of the browser window. Now that doesn't happen anymore. A big disadvantage IMHO.

Comment: The left navigation bar makes it all uncomfortable for people like me who are used to eye track from the left and compulsively detest repetitive and static element on page (like sticky nav or desktop ribbon). My programmatic eye-balls spends most time tracking left-to-center and only selectively track center-to-right content when needed to.  It gets annoying going back and forth between my left-oriented IDE and new center-oriented SO page.  I can only hide the left nav. Great if I can also collapse it.

Comment: Ugh just have an X button to hide it? Why make us go to our settings to hide it? Bad usability.

Comment: I personally feel it's ugly feature, even other devs in my company they were saying old stackoverflow was better (they are not registered), left nav occupies lot of space unnecessarily. Please remove this feature and revert to good old layout. So dowvoted (wish I was able to downvote multiple times to express dissatisfaction) :(

Comment: I like the new sidebar.

Comment: Looks great on my Nokia 3310!

Comment: You might have waited for [Flag Day](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/flag-day.html) to make the switch.

Comment: The new layout is more visually appealing, but the links aren't very relevant to me. For that left-nav I'd rather have filters on the feed than links to other areas of the site. I'd rather see those links in a dropdown menu from the top. I certainly use them all, but I often navigate straight there or go via my profile. They're just not very fitting on the feed. Tldr; style is way better, but I think the wrong content is emphasized.

Comment: I agree with @NateGardner -- the links feel useless to me, especially the create team since it goes to a paywall. I'm not against sidebars but so much real estate is used which doesn't concern me at all.

Comment: @NateGardner If you look at the [linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps?noredirect=1&lq=1), adding more useful content to the sidebar is actually part of the plans for the future. :)

Comment: I'm glad it's possible to turn the left-nav off, that's great. However with it's turned off old links aren't available in the top page with Questions, Tags, Users,  Badges, Unanswered. Where to find them then?

Comment: I think it is wrong to make less space for the Questions & Answers on a site like this. It feels like you are trying to say "Let's make Stackoverflow about stuff other than Q&A."

Comment: The navigation bar is reducing the information density on the page and the whole page looks bland since a lot of people are used to the previous design at this stage. What do you plan on using the screen estate for? Hope you folks don't go down the Reddit route of phasing out old design eventually.

Comment: I can't fond out how to get rid of this new feature!

Comment: @AlexJolig click on your rep, then edit profile and settings, site settings, preferences, find "hide left navigation"

Comment: I know stack is focus mainly (or at least seems to focus) on the team features as it's a good way to get money from the site, but SO is great for the community and the Q&A system. I hope with all this change it won't lose this.

Comment: At the moment I have no idea what this bar is for. It's not sticky on screen, it has links I never use (does someone really use those all the time?), it promotes Teams which I don't need... So will it at some point actually have some use? The right bar contents moved there, like favorite tags? That I didn't see answered here. So _why_ is this being added, and especially why _now_ that it has no content in it?

Comment: Just logged into SO today to find this useless sidebar. Then had to dig through a load of posts to find out how to get rid of it. I loved the old UI and have been using it for years. It wasn't broken - so did it need "fixing" ?

Comment: The negative feedback and downvotes are deserved--this is **objectively bad**.  You've pushed the content off to the right for a mostly empty slice of screen unless you're right at the top.  For that, the tabs were way, way better.  Please, revert this.

Comment: Waste of space. I couldn't find a way to collapse it, so I blocked the element with AdBlock.  Why don't you just put a pull-down nav at the top?

Comment: left sidebar looks absolutely amazing... [when turned off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/165773). <--- @MrZak referred post explains how to get to old links when it's off

Comment: It's new to me tho..I like it BTW!

Comment: @gnat I can't believe I missed that button since it was present for me all these several days since I disabled left-nav. Thanks for the link, now I know how to fight this (and now there are actually 2 hamburgers, one in the far right, one in the far left).

Comment: Plain simple: I don't like it. Its not my thing. I feel forced to log into SO just to be able to rid me of the left navigation. It uses a lot of screen real-estate for buttons I use very, very, very^10 infrequently.

Comment: At this point, the word "hamburger" has been mentioned 11 times on this page.

Comment: I was completely unaware that the profile and settings even existed, because so far no change to the site felt so terrible. The leftnav looks terrible, and defaulting to forcing it onto everyone is horrible. Please don't do this again. I signed up for Meta just to complain. Don't. Just Don't. Please!

Comment: What @MikeSpeed said. It's good to be able to hide the left nav bar, but we should be able to do that, au choix, either *everywhere* (all sites) or selectively *per site*. And we should be able to hide/show it by a click on the page where can appear, instead of having to navigate to a profile page. It should be a simple *toggle on the page itself*. And all of this assumes that we really have to have this thing. Do we? It seems to be a step backward - for us users, at least.

Comment: Is there a chance theoretically that we could get the previous design back? It was so much better.

Comment: I second what @CallumWatkins is asking. I really hope this is not another instance where a company has decided that **people will like this** and reality will not change their opinion.

Comment: @CallumWatkins Seconded, please just put it back how it was.  If SO was not responsive, (I wouldn't know, I'm never on it with a phone) then it should be set up for mobile, sure, but that's no reason to change the primary nav/layout for desktop.

Comment: @Josethehose Looks as bad as ever on mine... Do you use opera mini?

Comment: Using SO does feel terrible now. Even when i turn the side-nav off i feel bad when using the site. Maybe i should stop using this network for a couple of months hoping this bad feeling stops...

Comment: Whenever you release anything, you should also make it clear how to get rid of it. It would be an even better idea to give the users what they need rather than what you think they need. The post score clearly shows this change is not welcome, so you should follow your own principle of "downvote is disagreement on meta" and scrap this feature.

Comment: *"If you encounter a bug or a usability problem feel free to post it on MSE."* I take it that the *entire* change being a usability problem won't be treated very kindly by you, is this correct?

Comment: On my iPad the type font size is now way huge. I can’t see a whole question at once, let alone a question and it’s answer. Hiding the sidebar doesn’t fix it. Bring back the old design. It worked.

Comment: I must be missing something. I checked `Hide left navigation`, but it made no difference. On S.O. I still see the left part of the screen wasted on left nav stuff.

Comment: @Drew The "Hide left navigation" setting is per-site. The most common reason for someone having the problem you've mentioned is that they disabled it on one site, then went to another site. If interested, I created a userscript, [Left-sidebar in the Topbar](https://stackapps.com/q/7928/29529), which moves the left-sidebar into the topbar on all SE sites which have the left-sidebar, regardless of the preference set on each individual site. In other words, if you install that userscript, then you won't have to select the "Hide left navigation" setting on any sites.

Comment: Hear the voices, roll over the change.

Comment: Why all the hubbub over a navbar?  Just remove it and all problems are solved.

Comment: @Makyen: Got it; thx. I was doing it from this site (Meta). Duh.

Comment: Why is option to turn it off hidden away in settings? At initial launch it should be accessible right on the screen, in your face, for sometime. The UI of course sucks. I miss the old simple layout.

Comment: The new view isn't a big problem for me, actually the rectangular view looks awesome instead of the rounded-corners view. Also, the hamburger menu is working great. Btw, why so much downvotes to this post?

Comment: @Rahul the downvotes are from people who don't like the change and want the old design to be back.

Comment: If it isn't broken don't fix it.

Comment: Right now, the sidebar is a step backwards, but with some more useful buttons, it could be a big improvement. (So change the buttons and do what you need you do to make users happy with it **BEFORE** rolling it out to the othe communities.)

Comment: @Rahul See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Comment: What happened to viewing a list of all incoming new Questions, a total chronological list with newest at top?

Comment: @rafid059 care to explain how this "feels like Facebook" exactly??

Comment: @Shadow I can't speak for rafid, but if I had to guess: there's a "live feed" in the middle, "trending" stuff on the right, search box and notifications on top, a bunch of semi-useful links at the bottom and ... to complete the set ... a bunch of useless links on the left.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, what Thanos said. The problem is the left vertical border on the qa content. When I scroll down, the links on the left go away but the border remains. After a while there is nothing that border separates. There's just whitespace on the left of the border. That's what gives it a more facebooky feel. It's a small thing. But the main problem is that the links are now in the hamburger icon when I disable left sidebar from settings. I wish they would give us a setting that would put the links on the topbar again.

Comment: @Thanos what "live feed"? What "trending"? I'm afraid we're seeing two different things. On Stack Overflow, I see only the top bar, left nav bar, and the rest is the site contents. No feed, no trending stuff. The "bunch of useless links on the left" are the tabs, which used to be on top before, and the only way to navigate between Users, Tags, etc.

Comment: @Shadow He said *like* Facebook. "Trending" = Hot Network Questions. "Live feed"  = updates. In case of Facebook, it is posts, here it is questions. I thought you would see the correlation, so I put those in quotes. *"which used to be on top before"* Exactly, so why not keep it there? Let's also talk about that "etc." 2 links to SO *on* SO page (in addition to the one on top left). Two other (mostly) useless links to "Jobs" and Paywall (which are anyway found at the bottom). The only useful link there is "tags". Nothing that needs to be prominently included in a "left nav bar".

Comment: Atleast provide an option to "Switch to classic Stackoverflow..." or should have asked like "Try our new Stackoverflow"!

Comment: @MrZak A balanced diet is a hamburger in each hand. :)

Comment: It looks good and it looks bad for different reason

Comment: @MikeSpeed I suggested a [toggleable sidebar in my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310909/351462).

Comment: The new design wastes just as much space on top - it just has replaced the useful links with white space; now to use the site you need more waste space on the left! For extra waste there now seems to be white space on the right

Comment: Could we have an option to put the missing links in the now wasted area of the top bar?

Comment: Definitely feels like an ad for Teams. I'd like to be using teams but for me it's more of a company decision. This just puts it in my face constantly. Love the site in general and this isn't a huge deal, just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Thanos I hope they don't add go this route and add a Cola bottle in the middle then.

Comment: @MrZak Don't give them ideas. They might just do it. ;)

Comment: -157 net votes = disagreement. Can we revert to the old design now?

Comment: The "Disable top bar stickiness" option is available only in SO/MSO. When it will be added to other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: When is the schedule going to be updated, seeing how late June is over?

Comment: @ChristianRau Updated.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I don't think it's fair to conclude that the net vote count indicates disagreement. This may be the result of [self-selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-selection_bias). Those who are most disgruntled about the change will go out of their way to express their disagreement. It's likely there are many users who are neutral to the changes and didn't vote one way or the other, myself included.

Comment: *It's likely there are many users who are neutral to the changes and didn't vote one way or the other, myself included.* I think that agrees with my point. Net votes = Agree - Disagree, neutral people don't vote one way or the other.

Comment: Can we have a setting to revert back to the old UI? Just disabling still leaves this massive whitespace everywhere.

Comment: Thanks god, finally you have made the left sidebar. The very fact that the main text column is now more or less centered inside the view makes it **way better** for comfortable reading. So less need to tweak the site with userstyles, etc. BTW, since it's added - why not place some menu items there? I'd like "my profile" and "othe SE sites" items.

Comment: I think you should always be able to ask a question with "Ask Question" button. Currently if you are on the Tags or Users tab "Ask Question" button is not available.

Comment: Who asked for the left nav? Who out there scrolls to the bottom of a short SO page and says, "I need to see a list of users, RIGHT NOW"? This makes SO sooooo cluttered. What a terrible decision.

Comment: I hate the new theme for SU, and the new navigation, I am at the point where I dislike it so much I am thinking about deleting my account over it.  **I hate it that much.**

Comment: Not sure if this is where I should post, but ask ubuntu UI changed and became 'painful' (literally) for me to use. I get minimal text on screen, requiring scrolling. I have limited dexterity, and if adding a comment/question, the pgup allows scrolling upwards, but pgdn jumps to bottom of page. For those that can use mouse scroll wheels it's probably not an issue (just annoyance), but I can't due physical limitation (pain the movement causes).  The new UI just displays minimal without scrolling up/down which for me is a show stopper. I'm having to limit my time on askubuntu.com now

Comment: Are there any greeting cards for -200 votes? This is something special and hard to achieve!

Comment: @blub Happy to get a special badge to commemorate. I'm in rare company.

Comment: One more unhappy voice to add to the chorus.  I disabled the left nav pane but that leaves the right-hand pane far too wide.  FWIW - my browser occupies half of my 1920 x 1200 screen.  That makes the browser about 960 pixels wide.  The old layout worked very well, this new layout is darned uncomfortable.  Please try to make the new layout look more like the original.

Comment: What's about localized Stack Overflow sites? Fore example, Stack Overflow in Russian. Are you going to rollout it tomorrow for us too? 'cause I remember one thread ~3 weeks ago from you where you told that "you will rollout it in 1 week". But, 3 weeks already passed... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314345/unable-to-upload-an-image-or-even-close-upload-popup-when-responsive-design-is-o/314421#comment1030490_314421

Comment: @Suvitruf working on it as I type. Should happen tomorrow or early next week.

Comment: @JoeFriend any news? (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: @Suvitruf Should be going live tomorrow.

Comment: So much empty wasted space.

Answer (score 297):

1. Why is the search field so small?

   [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

   Meta SO:

   > [image: small search bar]

   SO (aka old situation) for comparison:

   > [image: normal search bar]
2. Also I find it annoying that the menu isn't always in the screen anymore (while there is plenty of space).

   [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> [Left nav is now sticky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311600/left-nav-is-now-sticky)

Now you either have to scroll up or open the hamburger menu first:

> [image]

It used to always be available on the top like this:

> [image]

3. Collapsing the menu doesn't really give you more space. I would expect the main part of the screen would use the space of the menu when it is collapsed.

   [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: Also on MSO (from me): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369072/search-bar-not-expanding-on-meta

Comment: How on earth has this been released with issue number 2?!

Comment: Just a thought, could we put a link back to main where the (*Questions* *Developer Jobs* etc.) links are for meta?. I find it annoyingly difficult having to dig in one of the many drop down menus to get back to main.

Comment: #2 appears to've been addressed.  When I narrow the window a hamburger menu appears with the questions/etc options in it.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Well, I'd argue it *hasn't* been released, for any sensible definition of "released"... it's a beta precisely for catching these issues.

Comment: @xDaizu Now it ***has*** been released, and it ***still*** doesn't scroll with the page!!!

Comment: indeed it look very bad with the empty left bar while hiding, I expect when hide the left bar, at least the content will occupy the empty space

Comment: _"Collapsing the menu doesn't really give you more space. I would expect the main part of the screen would use the space of the menu when it is collapsed"_ **HELL NO.** If you want that, ask for it as its own option! I do not want to have to choose between having a navbar or having a ridiculously wide page.

Comment: It become really weird to have navigation at left side of screen and not following screen when it was being scroll down.. Fell that the content here become more smaller than ever. Prefer the old version theme which make the content bigger and always have the menu up there whenever i scroll it

Comment: So much blank space to the left that I thought it might be full of ads I'm blocking.

Comment: For now, both of these issues are fixed on the com branch of [VisualCrumbs](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/tree/com)

Comment: Another time, please put things like this into 3 different answers, unless the issues are very closely coupled, which these are not. Grouping them into one answer makes it confusing what people are voting for. With one issue per answer it makes it much more clear how people feel about each bug/feature request.

Comment: @JoeFriend Can you please explain why bug 3 is status-declined?

Comment: @AndreKool, I generally search for tags, so search bar isn't a big problem with me. Further, I don't use the menu bar much often, not a problem, again. Finally, I have to ask, is there any way to reset the previous view?

Comment: @Thanos Bug 3 is not a bug, nor is the description accurate. At the max supported window size the left nav is added to the existing layout, thus when you take it away we don't expand the content. This is exactly how the site worked previously, we don't continue to expand the content area beyond a certain point to keep line lengths within a legible range.

Comment: This new layout is quite and rather claustrophobic on screen resolutions less than 1600x1200/1680x1050. I browse the SE networks at 1024x768/1280x1024 and already frequently find myself hitting ^- to zoom-out the page to 66-80% of the default size just to see more than a paragraph on screen. This layout is also not friendly towards non-widescreen viewing, or windowed layouts that are taller than they are wide. The sidebar is mildly distracting while scrolling to read text. An account-wide flag for the setting and a more accessible toggle would be a nice compromise to change.

Answer (score 244):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (see [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com))

My first impression of the left nav was pretty negative. All I saw there were links I didn't care about, and any time I went to a question list, the first thing I saw on every load was the navbar, and as I was reading through the questions, my focus kept switching to the new navbar on the left. I'm sure a lot of that was because it was new, but it kept happening, and it was frustrating. Disabling it made me feel better about it.

Now, however, after discussing it for a bit, testing it, messing around with it, I do think the only real problem I had with it was I felt like it was distracting me, pulling my attention away from what I was looking for. I found that one small change made all the difference for me, and that was giving the body of the page a background color. It didn't matter what color it was, as long as it put the primary content of the page into a separate box from the navbar on the left, it no longer distracted me. Here I just pulled the background from the header and added missing borders.

[image]

I can of course make this change myself later via a userscript if it doesn't go live, but that's my suggestion.

Comment: This would be nice... particularly if they integrate a way to minimize the left sidebar in the page directly rather than in a settings menu (which was, I think, the intention at some point)... I agree that the white background draws more attention when offset with the pale grey

Comment: You don't use the questions menu? I do because it shows meta questions which have collected a few to a lot of downvotes.

Comment: yeah i prefer the home page on SO, so that’s where i go on meta

Comment: Ooh, I kind of like that. Even a slight tone change makes it a lot more instant to parse the "sections" of the page.

Comment: I also notice this “pull” you're describing. Comes to mind: In comic layout design, elements we want to draw attention to are supposed to stand out from the rest of the panel content. ([Aaron Diaz describes this here](http://dresdencodak.tumblr.com/post/1279958363/silhouettes-the-silent-killer), e.g. see [this comic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gBFW8.jpg). Warning, other posts on that blog may be NSFW.) Our left menu sticks out distinctly the same way, esp. the active navigation item which has a highlight to it and is just a single rectangle poking out of the side of the content like a flag.

Comment: If anyone else wants to try this, here's the custom style I'm using (via [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne)): `body { background-color: #fafafb } #content { border-right: 1px solid #d6d9dc }`

Comment: @Josh That makes a world of difference.

Comment: This should also be implemented on the right sidebar. There's sooo much content fighting for attention otherwise.

Comment: Why isn't there a `Refined StackOverflow` like there is Refined [GitHub](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github), [Twitter](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-twitter) and [Wikipedia](https://github.com/ismamz/refined-wikipedia)?

Comment: Now if only we could lose the "Create Team+" and "Public" header on SO. Looks great everywhere else

Answer (score 198):

That menu has a *lot* of whitespace; I mean a *lot*.

[image: left-nav]

And yet even with my rather large browser window it pushes the content to the right slightly. I'm guessing it's so darn big to accommodate large team names; but this still feel really excessive.

**I expected it to hug the actual side of the screen.**

GIF of the content jumping when nav is introduced (fullscreen, 1920x1080, Edge):

[image]

Comment: The exact amount it pushes content over is `70px`, btw. You can use [these styles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZaQu.png) to set it to the side of the screen, recenter the main body 70px left, and have the sidebar links scroll with you as you scroll down, as a temporary fix (only works on fullscreen at 1080px wide)

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't replicate that.

Comment: @JoeFriend Microsoft Edge 41.16299.402.0

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Still no repro. If I open the site in Edge I see the same amount of white space on both sides of the  screen on a full width window. Can you see if you can repro in another browser? If you can't is it possible that something strange is conflicting (extensions or something)?

Comment: @JoeFriend There may well be the same amount of whitespace on both sides; the content definitely moves though when the left nav is turned on/off (even fullscreened) I have to move my mouse to toggle the checkbox again. I have no extensions installed (not even Adblock). My expectation is that the left nav would just "eat up" some of the existing whitespace rather than shove everything to the right.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Somehow I'm not understanding your issue. Want to capture a gif of the interaction you're seeing? Sorry for being clueless.

Comment: @JoeFriend Added GIF; you can see the checkbox (and the rest of the content) jump when I enable the nav bar.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the GIF. What exactly is the impact of the problem you're seeing. Obviously you're not going to be switching back and forth. So do you want to use pinned or unpinned left nav? And with the pref set for that how are you negatively impacted? Again, sorry for being slow.

Comment: @JoeFriend Mostly its just weird that everything I'm used to scanning at a particular spot on the page (votes, etc) is now shifted over. I'm sure I could get used to it over time, but :(. At the moment I'm leaving the left nav turned off due to this. Love the idea in general, just wish it was implemented a little differently.

Comment: If the page content is centered in the window, then reducing the width of the content wider will increase the margin on both sides. In other words, when you remove the sidebar, the left margin gets only half of its width - causing the apparent edge of the content to move left. The alternatives here would be always expanding to fill all available space (terrible for reading on wide windows) or always reserving an extra margin on the left when the sidebar isn't displayed (which would somewhat negate the purpose of having a hide option and make the page look stupid).

Comment: I wonder if this is partly related to the fact that the user pages aren't yet part of responsive design... if you make the page too narrow, you get a side scroll... if you want to see whether it's centered or not you need to look at one of the pages that *is* part of responsive design.

Comment: @JoeFriend The left nav moves the main content of the site to the right, it's no longer centered. It takes away the balance of the site, without symmetrical balance things looks cluttered and feels uncomfortable.

Comment: It's definitely still centered, @Spencer; measure it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Shog9 No it's definitely not. Re-read my comment. You can also compare it by setting the left-nav to display: none. The shift of the main content is most definitely shifted right.

Comment: Here, @Spencer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqImn.png - count off the tic marks.

Comment: @Shog9 Because the left and right sidebars aren't the same width, on smaller screen widths than the full-width resolution, it is actually off-center. The two red lines [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNouI.png) are the same length.

Comment: Wait, *that's* the argument? That the left sidebar is narrower than the right? Yeah... that's probably not gonna change @Catija; already some folks are complaining that it takes up too much room (myself included).

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what Spencer is talking about but that's how I interpreted it... Though, that actually exists regardless of the page width, now that I think of it... but... if that's the case, the site was never really "centered" since the question content has never had a left sidebar at all... so if anything, it's *more* centered than it was, sandwiched between two sidebars rather than the right-only one. There's also about 10 px of padding on the right sidebar, which might make it look off center, @Shog9

Comment: @Shog9 `#mainbar` and `#sidebar` is the content of the website on the Questions pages. Likewise `#content` is the main content on the profile page, this may be a better example. The locations of these items currently where always centered, which in combination is the main content of the page. With the inclusion of `#left-sidebar` while it may be considered an element, it doesn't have any content and is mostly empty space.

Comment: So, @SpencerWieczorek would you say that [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OepxJ.png) is what you're talking about being "off center"?

Comment: The page margins - which is what this answer is about - are external to #container, @Spencer. You might want to post a separate answer; the very large amount of wasted whitespace *under* the sidebar menu has been noted before, but certainly still remains an issue.

Comment: @Catija Correct.

Comment: Screen Real-Estate is at a premium on laptops. Why fix what isn't broken and waste the whole left side of the browser window in the process. Even hidden the left-nav is a distraction and a whole additional vertical section of SO that is just ripe for future exploitation and distraction from the main purpose of SO. The top-nav is correct interface design, provides the needed functionality in a minimum amount of space, and doesn't provide empty-space to be taken up in the future by more cruft that distracts from the primary purpose of SO for the end user.

Comment: I can replicate this on other browsers as well on 1920x1080.

Comment: Can replicate on Chrome 67.0.3396.79 on MacOS 10.13.4 (1280x800 scaled)

Comment: Chrome latest version on windows 10, I have this big space on left, resolution 1920x1080 on 24" screen, i is annoying especially I'm on working in 2 screens, I find myself looking into the farthest right!

Comment: The content is much too small. What is the purpose of having a wide screen then?

Comment: It feels like I need to tuck my shoulders in to read SO with this new layout, almost a third of my screen is whitespace!

Comment: @JasonBassford Can you post an answer with more information including screenshots/gif of what you're seeing.

Comment: I see this in Firefox as well, There is so much dead space on the left.

Comment: I recently bought a new computer (iMac) with a larger screen to cope with my failing eyesight - even so I need to view at 130% to read. I **don't** want **ANY** whitespace!

Comment: I have this in Opera. Is there some kind of client side script that could fix this styling?

Answer (score 121):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In my opinion, I think the highlight on the tabs should be on the left side. It flows better, because, like most other tab highlights in the UI, they flow top => down or left => right (at least for LTR languages)

Additionally, the highlight bar butting up against a single pixel gray vertical line is jarring and distracting depending on the content in the center panel.

When on the left, it still highlights the tab, doesn't look like a scrollbar (as per the comments), and doesn't clash with the vertical line content separator. The only difference is it pushes the text in the tab in by the width of the border, so the words don't exactly line up.

Current:

[image: Highlight on right side]

Tweaked:

[image: Highlight on left side]

Comment: I actually thought the orange highlight was a scrollbar at first

Comment: I actually like this idea.  It does look like a scroll bar if it is on the right (as it currently is).  If it were on the left I guess it would be a scroll bar if you were reading arabic pages?

Comment: I like this suggestion a lot, went ahead and added it to my [VisualCrumbs](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/tree/com) userscript. Thank you!

Comment: I gave this my upvote already, but I feel like this point is well illustrated by the screenshots and well worth consideration by the devs!

Answer (score 117):

Sacrificing more of my screen real estate for showing things I do not need is *not* an improvement.

Even with the left bar switched off (thanks for this option, as such) I now see 40% of my right margin occupied by things which were previously hidden away in the margin.

Here is the Stack Overflow start page as of today:

[image: Stack Overflow start page]

I mean ... seriously!?

Promoting navigation aids and advertising over actual content is not "responsive" at all in my book.

The left bar adds insult to injury by doing the same on the left-hand side.  I can understand how menus make some things slightly less discoverable (and frankly, the menu design on this site is really not transparent, consistent, or logical) but putting trainer wheels on everyone's bikes just because there are some beginners who cannot yet ride without them is a terrible design.

I like Kevin B's proposal to move the left bar into the top bar; having the main content assaulted from both margins is a losing proposition, whereas having stuff tucked away at the top (and ideally scrollable out of sight ... though that too is now a tick box you have to discover in your preferences!) so you can get your designated window filled with the actual content you want to look at would work pretty well.  If you have to make the top bar higher or more complex to accommodate proper menus, so be it.

Comment: There are now three hamburger menus: One on the left (if you click away the left bar), one with a checkmark on it (review queues) and one with a stem (the rightmost community icon).  This really doesn't pass the laugh/cry test.

Comment: The review queues icon is not a hamburger...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was imprecise. There are three menus whose icons look vaguely like (Minecraft) hamburgers, but obviously only *one* of them is *the* hamburger.

Comment: @tripleee There are actually 5-6 menus in the top bar depending on if you have left nav pinned or not. Left nav, inbox, achievements, review queues, help, and site switcher. They generally look and work in the same way.

Comment: @JoeFriend The point I'm trying to make is that three of them are indistinguishable by quick glance. If you tell somebody "find the hamburger menu" and they look on the rigth, there are two of them there which look like good candidates, but aren't. I'm not a fan of tiny monochrome icons as menu items in the first place; there really isn't any way to guess what they contain. Maybe that's what's actually pushing you away from using proper menus in the first place? I know it's not web3.0 sexy but "review queue" and "site selector" would work a lot better than hamburgers with different handicaps.

Comment: Er... what browser, resolution, and zoom level is that screenshot taken with? Are you sure you don't have any scripts running and have not manually scrolled down and over to the right?

Comment: @tripleee Also, hovering over each of these icons (which I find easily distinguishable from one another and only one of them could possibly be confused with a hamburger menu - the Stack Exchange menu icon on the far right) will produce a tooltip with the long form description of what each icon links to.

Comment: @TylerH This is Chrome on Mac OS High Sierra MacBook Pro, 15" (I think) Retina display. No zoom and no horizontal scrolling, though obviously I have scrolled down to illustrate how the "hot posts" column is filled with white when you do that.

Comment: Having a tooltip when you hover is hardly sufficient to make it obvious what the icons represent. What I'm trying to say is that if usability testing revealed that new users cannot find stuff which is now in the left bar, perhaps fixing the menus so you could guess what they do would have been a less intrusive change.

Comment: Visiting in private mode looks slightly less annoying (only about 15% white with the same screen width); I guess this is worse for Teams members.

Comment: @Tyler: I've been using SO for years, and ever since the top bar re-design a year or so ago I still have no idea what most of the buttons do. The problem is that there are too many low-contrast icons that look fairly similar. Furthermore, it's not obvious that they're drop-down menus (I still expect them to bring me to a different page), and the only way to identify them is through the tooltip. Each button should be labeled and there should be some indication that a menu will open (down triangle, etc.).

Comment: @Makyen has a userscript for moving the left bar to the top bar: https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/blob/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js

Comment: *"Promoting navigation aids and advertising over actual content is not "responsive" at all in my book."* This! A million times this! Putting more ads is fine with me, but don't justify it with flimsy excuses like "responsive". I see that @JoeFriend chose to respond to that criticism with ... ignoring it entirely! Why can't you just say, "we are introducing left nav bar so that more people will look at Teams, and we will get a bigger bonus"? Be sincere.

Answer (score 104):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**YAWC (yet another whitespace complaint)**

When viewing a Question page on mobile, it feels like there is too much whitespace under the voting buttons, and especially to the left of comments. Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: New design]

Compare this with the mobile theme, which has no whitespace since the voting buttons are positioned next to the question title:

[image: Mobile theme]

Would it be possible to move the voting buttons to be next to the question title when the viewport is at a mobile size?

Comment: Actually, yes. Right now posts end up being extremely long on my phone because there is so little horizontal spacing for the content... but I also think the question states that the mobile version is still in the works... "*We haven't fully optimized this for mobile device*"

Comment: @Catija correct, we haven't fully optimized for mobile. That said, this is an excellent point for when we do.

Comment: If you think *that's* a lot of whitespace, look at how much more there is on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDF0o.png

Comment: What about for answers? They don't really have a title, so eliminating the whitespace beside the question itself won't do much because it will still exist for answers

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton You're right. The current mobile theme (not new design) also has this issue. However I think that there is even more whitespace  than the mobile theme. It seems this is due to comments being double indented. First indent for being a sub-item of questions/answers and ANOTHER indent for upvote/flag button. OTOH, the mobile theme seems to only have one indent level for upvote/flag button.

Comment: @KodosJohnson If people could agree to have a little bit more vertical space, maybe above answers you could include information about the poster instead of at the bottom of the question (or something similar, anything really that will allow each answer to have it's own sort of "title" which you could then move the up/downvotes next to. Or perhaps the up/downvote buttons could be move to the bottom of the question where there is already a tiny bit of whitespace due to the share/edit/flag etc links

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think that would be a good solution.

Answer (score 88):

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
>
> We considered this, but have some features coming that will need the space.

#### #1: I suggest that we shrink the navbar in width to about the width of the longest item ("Questions" in this case).

[image: Shrunken sidebar(Click to enlarge)]

I want it because the button I most frequently will be "Questions". Hence, I will only use 25% of the bar, so I want thing I will use rarely to take up as little space as possible. And I don't want to do 2 clicks to get there.

#### #2: Make sidebar `position: fixed;` for quicker access

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> [Left nav is now sticky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311600/left-nav-is-now-sticky)

Currently when we scroll to the bottom of the page and the horizontal bar is sticky I can "refresh" questions section by making a single click on "Questions" in navbar:

[image: Topbar with fixed position]

But the new sidebar gets hidden on scroll down and now we are no longer a single click away from the "Questions" section, but `position: fixed` can fix that:

[image: Sidebar with fixed position]

And when both changes above are applied, together with the suggestion about grey background from another answer, we get small, convenient sidebar:

[image: Shrunken sidebar with fixed position]

#### #3: Replace sidebar text with icons

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
>
> We considered this approach but it is very hard to find icons that are easily identifiable to a large majority of people.

... or we could make such an option available to be toggled in user preferences.

[image: Sidebar with icons]

This will further improve allocation of space.

---

Comment: *Why* do you want that?

Comment: Remember that this sidebar is used for other things besides these four menu items, and some have longer names than "Questions."

Comment: @Nathaniel I assumed so. But I, personally, don't see those long-name items. It's possible to compute how wide sidebar can be based on what items are available.

Comment: Okay; I didn't realize you meant make it dynamic based on the elements in the bar; I understood it as fixed 80px.

Comment: @AlexL you don't have to, because the browser does it automatically when the text changes! :)

Comment: @user1306322 Yes, but in this case, apparently, they designed it in such way that it does not do it automatically for whatever reason. Regardless, I don't care how it will be implemented, as long as there is less blank space that I see.

Comment: @AlexL yea, I mean if you `unset` the pre-set width, it should automatically increase its width to fit the text (but you should probable add padding for some visual beauty). They most probably set it for a consistent look across all languages and available fonts. In any case, i don't see why you should use that bar at all if you have an option to disable it either via personal settings or via css scripts hiding it, to the same effect.

Comment: #3 is basically what the sidebar needs IMO. It's less distracting and takes less space - the current one looks really bad on 1280x1024 screens, like my secondary one, it takes a lot of space, and margin on the left is too small, which is ugly.

Comment: Also, non-descriptive icons (Without a label) are long time considered a really bad approach to UX.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan 1. There are only 4 buttons here, and 99.9%+ of users on SO will have no trouble figuring out what those 4 new icons do. 2. If they really want they can add text description on hover, the way taiga.io does it. 3. In current navbar we already have "icons only" where icon description is in the `title` attribute.

Comment: Pictograms/icons would be awsome!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan in which century? Icons or pictograms are much easier and faster to understand because you just recognize them instantly, you don't have to read all this stuff everytime. You look at it and you know what it is. I think you've learned UI design from the wrong books. I despise text, if it's not the actual content then it's always distracting taking much longer to find what I need than by seeing only pictures.

Comment: @shiny-metal, pictograms are faster to understand once you've learned them.  If you *haven't* learned them (like about 90% of the site visitors), the meaning is completely opaque.  Text has the advantage that it doesn't require learning.

Comment: @Mark the entire upper menu is just pictograms and nobody complains about it. Most of the page buttons etc are images, downvote, up vote, community switching, help, reputation etc. Your browser uses icons for navigation, there is no back and forth labels, there is also no home label.

Comment: @shiny-metal, *your* browser uses icons for navigation.  Mine's still got old-fashioned labeled pictures.

Comment: I like all the suggestions except the pictograms, which have historically been unsuccessful UX on SO and SE for various reasons and A/B testing proved it.

Comment: @Patrick Well, then maybe "get better at picking those icons" is the way to go as against "we failed at this, so let us never try it again". They could also post questions on [UX.se] if they want to improve their UX skills.

Comment: @shiny-metal, From UX.StackExchange & Neilson/Norman Group Research: [Icons Need a Text Label](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/64494/34594)

Comment: @KyleMit then how do you explain traffic signs that work without labels or the many symbols in cars or everywhere else? Text is always distracting and this can be seen on the page you quoted which is all text! They took their text rules to heart. To understand text you have to read it and this costs you a lot of time. When you see images you just get it and you don't have to stop not even for a moment... but it doesn't apply when there is a text next to them because it draws your attention away from the symbol so it's pretty useless then.

Comment: @shiny-metal, I'd encourage you to share some of those observations in the UX thread as a way to further dialog about some of the pros / cons of icons / labels.  Shortly, the symbols you mentioned work in isolation largely because of their universal adoption.  Ask 10 different people to draw a "tags" symbol separately and you'll get a bunch of different designs.  Ask 10 new people to deserialize it back into text and you might not land back in the same place.  Ultimately, it's about cognitive load to parse, and people are different. Research can help determine what is best for most, not all.

Comment: @KyleMit Please look at this image of [3DS Max](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8Dphn95ESGQ/maxresdefault.jpg). I counted ~100 icons without labels. Yet people have no problem using this software once they learn what those icons do. In our case we need only 4 icons. **I don't want to suffer becausea few people out there can't understand/memorize what 4 icons do**. Those 10-20 people who struggle with "tags" symbol **can and should learn that symbol**. Why do we try to satisfy people who can't learn? They have to step up their game. Regardless, **we can allow toggling icons/labels in settings**.

Answer (score 83):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Instead of adding a "hide" option in user settings, have you considered making the sidebar toggleable with a button instead?

[image: Example of a toggleable sidebar]

Advantages of a togglable sidebar:

- Site maintains a consistent look and feel between users.
- More intuitive than searching through settings menus<sup>1</sup>.
- Doesn't require changing site-specific preferences on each community.
- Guests can hide/show the sidebar without needing to login.
- Fewer preferences help [keep the options menu simple](https://blog.codinghorror.com/keeping-the-menu-simple/).

<sup><sup>1</sup>Currently, disabling the sidebar involves navigating through 
*User Profile → Edit Profile & Settings → Preferences → Navigation → Hide left navigation*.</sup>

Comment: But the features are available in the (new) hamburger menu in the upper left?

Comment: We considered this and other approaches. They all have various strengths and weaknesses. We decided on the pref approach best met the goals of the feature.

Comment: @JoeFriend What about it being a per-site feature rather than network wide? Is this just minor mistake due to lack of testing or a deliberate decision? Or is it worth opening a feedback answer for that?

Comment: @ChristianRau we don't have global prefs today. It would be work to add it. We've considered it in the past and never had enough to bother. Most people never change the pref. For those that do they set it in the handful of communities they actively participate in and never look at it again. Maybe this will be the tipping point?

Comment: Hmm, the hiding seems like something many people like, especially power users (i.e. multi-siters?). But once you consider making it sticky (as repeatedly proposed here), that would definitely be a tipping point. For now making the top-bar sticky only *worked* on SO, but once we *could* be able to sticky the sidebar, too (provided you consider that), it seems reasonable to consider making it a network-wide feature in the same go. A workaround could be having a button to copy the changes to every profile, like with the name changes. That *should* work even without explicit network-wide features.

Comment: +1 if for no other reason than because some option hidden in the settings somewhere seems more likely to conveniently disappear or stop working at some point in the future.

Comment: Other reason to have it toggled. I am often use PC and iPad. Left nav is ok for PC, but not good for iPad( too much real estate taken). Keep changing preferences is not convenient.

Comment: @JoeFriend, Preferences are not discoverable. I wanted just to collapse left nav, because it takes too much space on iPad, but instead of tap small “”toggle” button had to search meta until I find this discussion and point to preferences. It is not user friendly.

Comment: If simply toggling it saves the setting globally, this might be inconvenient with tabbed browsing. If you like it off by default, then enable it, then forget to disable it, then open a bunch of tabs, all those tabs would have it on. We could somewhat solve that by making the toggle toggle it on all open tabs, but that doesn't sound like a good idea. So simply toggling it should probably not be a global change, but rather just for that tab, and then there's another option to toggle it globally (but then we're basically back to what we have now, except maybe it's not hidden in the settings).

Comment: @JoeFriend I participate a number of communities (with a different frequency of'course) and visiting the maze of settings for each of them is not nice experience...

Comment: @JoeFriend Have you considered simply making the left navigation hamburgered (I hope I use the right word)? That is, not _hide it_, but rather _collapse it into icons only_. See [OPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvBcF.png) vs [CLOSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzwGw.png) in a system I use elsewhere.

Comment: @yo' We did think about that. It can be difficult to come up with icons, but that is still an approach that we are considering for the future.

Comment: @JoeFriend In that case I would like to kindly ask you to consider it as soon as possible, because if would allow for the main panel not to get so squeezed, and that would be a huge improvement.

Comment: I will be yet another voice asking for at-the-least a toggle-option somewhere on the page and NOT hidden away on the options page. I had no idea this sidebar could even be toggled until I was perchance guided here by one of the 'featured on ..." boxes on the right sidebar navigation

Answer (score 51):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Once again the design completely ignores people who use small screens or who use a window interface :(

This is the new MSO at 816px (on my system, YMMV), with the left sidebar disabled:

[image: 816 is the magic number]

This is a bit too narrow for me though. I'd rather have a window that's half the width of my monitor, which on the machine I'm posting on right now is 1920. But widen the window to 817px and beyond, and it breaks down (or breaks up?):

[image: 817 is the number of the devil]

WHY???

I'm not even sure whether the narrow-screen behavior is intended or not. I guess an accommodation for mobile devices? Please keep it! Please, please keep it!

And please **make the right side-bar collapsible**, like the left side-bar is**. This shouldn't be a preference, it should be a button that you click (with a discoverable keyboard shortcut, of course).

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

By the way, collapsing the left sidebar shouldn't be a user preference. Its desirability depends on the window width, so it should be possible to toggle it on a window by window basis. I think a decent compromise would be to make it a hidden preference that you can quickly toggle on the page, possibly a cookie-based rather than account-based preference since optimum window size tends to be device-dependent.

Comment: They could also increase the threshold that determines when the sidebar stacks.

Comment: How can you resist the temptation to not click that `+3903` shiny green notif?

Comment: @Frakcool I've never understood the appeal. I know intellectually that some people are obsessed with numbers and that Stack Exchange's philosophy is to pander to those people, but I have neither the time nor the inclination to watch every vote, badge and whatnot. I hide it with CSS most of the time. I only reset it every few weeks or so when I accidentally press the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I see, interesting tho

Comment: +3903 rep? wow... I can't resist when I get past 30... and sadly I don't think I've ever been passed 100 :-(

Comment: @Gilles: I sometimes go have a look at old answers that are getting votes long after I posted them, and see if there's anything to tidy up.  Many old answers dwell in obscurity, but some actually get a reasonable amount of search hits.  Those are the ones I want to make sure are definitely giving advice I still think is correct. :P

Comment: @Frakcool I choked on my coffee when I saw that. How could anyone resist clicking that? Holy crap that's a lot of unread rep notifications.

Comment: @Clonkex If that had a badge.

Comment: @PeterCordes I guess it's a matter of scale. I don't have time for that. Now can everybody please **[stop commenting on an irrelevant detail](https://xkcd.com/1373/)**?.

Comment: An xkcd link... yup that should redirect everyone's attention nicely :P

Comment: I actually have the opposite experience. I like seeing the stuff on the right, but my default browser window size on my vertical monitor it is way at the bottom. I do like the idea of an easy collapse/expand for it. Open when I want to see related links, closed when I'm viewing answers.

Answer (score 43):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> see [Left nav is now sticky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311600/left-nav-is-now-sticky)

I wouldn't normally request a per-user feature as it's a lot of work, but as you already have the per-user options for navigation, can we have an option to make the new left nav fixed?

So it will always be there when scrolling (or not if preferred).

With the option already present to "disable top bar stickiness", this new requested feature will allow users to select their preferred menu to always be visible to be clicked. Or both if preferred.

Comment: I get content not scrolling with the page if theres a lot of team related content, but I've only got 4 items in the list. Why dont those items move down when I scroll? Whats the point of them having their own content box if 90% of the time that box is empty?

Comment: In the mean time you can apply this yourself with Stylish or other User Style browser addon with the following styles: `#left-sidebar nav[role="navigation"] { position: sticky; top: 75px; }` on browsers that support `position: sticky;`

Comment: Don't forget that the current content of the left sidebar is not likely to stay what it is. From other posts it seems like there will eventually be much more content moved to or added to the left sidebar including favorite tags and custom searches. Fixing the left nav would require a secondary scroll bar depending on what is added to this space and how it's implemented.

Comment: I kind of like how [Read the Docs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) does this —    the sidebar content scrolls with the main page, but it can also be scrolled separately and it won’t scroll out of view.

Comment: Having the left sidebar NOT fixed in place seems quite useless to me.  The point of nav is to allow navigation, and if I have scroll back to the top to use it I'll just keep it in the header instead.  This wasn't though out very well.

Comment: @ExUmbris : If only that option existed...

Answer (score 43):

> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
>
> The current behavior is a bit a of a hack that we need to clean up. I think the direction we will move is: * some things (possibly the asked/viewed/active meta data) will get integrated into the post itself * some things get moved to the bottom (related) * and some things get dropped altogether (hot posts)

You mentioned the site is now responsive. At first glance, I love that you hid the right sidebar at smaller resolutions and then I realized... nope, you just *moved it to the bottom of the page*:

[image: right sidebar below the answer box]

Is this really the intended design on smaller resolutions?

Comment: That's a bit a of a hack that we need to clean up. I think the direction we will move is:
* some things (possibly the asked/viewed/active meta data) will get integrated into the post itself
* some things get moved to the bottom (related)
* and some things get dropped altogether (hot posts)

Comment: Hot posts is about 70% of the content I browse. Is there a replacement planned, or a meta post about this?

Comment: @battery.cord you can get the full hot list (not just a selection from it) on a page of its own by clicking the "Hot Network Questions" header.  That might be  worth bookmarking for your browsing convenience; you can scan 50 questions at a time there.

Comment: @JoeFriend that's good to hear.  I hope that the community bulletin and (on sites where it exists) the professional disclaimer will continue to be prominent.

Comment: +927392755 to no longer wasting space on every page with trending distractions.

Comment: This seems to be common behavior of sidebars for responsive sites

Comment: Why would you actively make a sidebar inaccessible? Pushing down is the right thing.

Comment: What do you mean by smaller resolutions? Screens with small resolution?

Comment: @NogShine So, I run my web browsers maximized (fullscreen) typically. My monitor resolution is 1920x1080. Not everyone uses 1920x1080; some people still run at 1024x768. And some people run at much smaller tablet-sized resolutions in browsers that don't shrink the pixels to accommodate "HD" resolutions on those devices. Aside from that, there is always the real possibility that many users simply won't run the browser window maximized. They may need to see a webpage and another application at the same time, side-by-side. This shrinks the browser viewport resolution.

Comment: @Nemo The sidebar is not required for the main function of the site. It is all "extra" flashy stuff. Announcements! Hot questions! Other networks! A lot of users aren't interested in that stuff one bit. Many others are only interested in the announcements. Even more only want to see "related questions". In my personal opinion, hiding it with the option to have it slide out at a fixed position w/ higher z-index on icon click (or something similar) is the ideal solution. No need to scroll down to see it or scroll side to side to see the full view of the page at smaller resolutions.

Comment: Oh! I understood what you meant. I too have an opinion that this is a design intended for 1280x1024, 1600x1200. You face problem due to large window and I face with smaller window. I still use 1024x768. The content looks sandwiched due to that. There are bugs too.

Comment: _"That's a bit a of a hack"_ Understatement of the year.

Answer (score 32):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please reduce the amount of space tags take at the top, and add clear indicators for different tags.

This:

[image]

is plain horrible. I've lost about 30% of the vertical space on my (small) second monitor purely on tags.

Comment: I cam here to post this! +1

Comment: I have [this tags](https://goo.gl/Nmu2Jx)  (note: goo.gl shortened link because it could not fit in the comment) always open due to my interests, and I can't see questions without scrolling. I think showing this header is a good idea, but have some limits: if the header would take >50% of the screen, reduce the font, revert back to the side tags, make it collapsible showing only the channel, ...

Comment: Also, previously the total questions for a tag was shown on the right side of the page and it was bold and big. Easy to spot. That is information which is valuable to users. Now it's small and not-so-easy to spot

Comment: It looks like [this](https://image.ibb.co/h7EOFJ/jdasis.png) using the latest version of [VisualCrumbs](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/tree/com) in the Com branch. @Jofre

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369366/1630171).

Comment: [This is fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311239/dont-put-the-searched-tags-on-top-of-stackoverflow/311850#311850)

Answer (score 30):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

You've changed the color of the 'Ask Question' button on the ['active' tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active):

[image]

but not on the other tabs, like [hot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot):

[image]

and the [/questions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/), as [@rene noted on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369070/meta-so-ask-question-button-has-wrong-coloring#comment597531_369070).

Comment: The individual question pages also have the old button.

Comment: Now that it's live on Meta Stack Exchange, the Ask Question button is blue-on-white, but the same problem remains.

Comment: I guess due to effect of heat the `div` 's physical property is changed. :-D

Answer (score 29):

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> See [Hide Left nav everywhere with a global preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311528/hide-left-nav-everywhere-with-a-global-preference)

**Left nav pin/unpin should be a global, cross-site pref**

I set the preference to collapse the left side bar (“Hide left navigation”) via Meta Stack Overflow, and it's working there. But on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, the left side bar is not collapsed and the preference checkbox in my profile is unticked.

User interface preferences should obviously not depend on the site. I'm not going to edit my profile on over a hundred site!

Yes, I know this is an old bug, keyboard shortcuts have had the same problem for years. So please solve it already!

Comment: @JoeFriend “feature request”? Come on, that's petty. It is not reasonable to expect users to repeat an action over a hundred times.

Comment: For users that are active on more than one or two sites this limitation means that the preference essentially doesn't exist. It's not reasonable to manually set it on every single site (and meta site).

Comment: @Gilles Seriously did not mean to be petty in any way. It isn't a bug, it is a feature. We need to plan for it and add significant code to support it. It was requested when we took the top bar network wide and we ended up not doing it due to cost. That said, I'm a supporter of the request. That is why I made the edit. It was in no way a dig or slight.

Comment: In Wikimedia it took 10 years to get seriously *started* on this feature from the moment global accounts were introduced. ^_^ https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Community_Tech/Global_preferences

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was disabled on meta and stackoverflow when I checked the box yesterday, but a few hours later it came back on stackoverflow and I had to search for the stackoverflow preferences to disable it there too.

Answer (score 29):

## Add Help, Meta and Chat links into the sidebar.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[image: site switcher: stack overflow, help, chat, log out, meta stack overflow.]

The site switcher contains some pretty major site navigation features. I'd classify them as equally important as being able to navigate to users and tags, if not more important or more likely to be used.

What if we added these to the sidebar?

> [image: a screenshot of the left sidebar, with some new options added.]
>
> New: “Chat” and “Help” added at the bottom (the help link with its help icon to help users find it); "Meta Stack Overflow" added beneath the Stack Overflow link.

These weren't previously listed alongside Questions/Tags/Users/Jobs because that was a horizontal menu with limited space. Now we've got a vertical menu that doesn't have the same constraints.

## Add My Communities as well [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

(I've just seen [Monica Cellio also mentioned this as part of her feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309380/152515), but I think it makes sense to leave this here too whilst I'm talking about adding site switcher content to the sidebar.)

We could even move the My Communities section of the site switcher into the sidebar. It'll be appearing on every site, right? So now I can move around to other sites this way.

> [image]

I'm not sure how I'd execute “More Stack Exchange communities” since we wouldn't want a list of all 200+ communities showing up in the sidebar, but if we added that section & functionality into the sidebar too, it would make the site switcher obsolete.

A valid counter-argument for this section is to consciously keep the sidebar limited to navigating locally within the one stack exchange site, and keep the site switcher for the task of navigating to other sites.

Comment: Looks like you understood what "primary navigation" means. ;) +1 to this. If this gets implemented, I will delete my answer below asking to hide the left navigation bar by default. I still don't see "Jobs" as anything more than a useless nuisance, but I agree with your overall answer, so I will ignore that. ;)

Comment: I could do without the site-switcher, but the first suggestion looks AWESOME. Would also address: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369680/back-to-so-from-som

Comment: +1, but one thing: in the mockup it sorta looks like tags/users/jobs/chat are nested under meta, by dint of the presence/absence of an icon. (Add to that the familiarity many might have with site metas "owning" users and tags pages....) I'm no UI sheep, though, so I've got no good suggestion for how to improve it =(

Comment: @nitsua60 List it last (after "Help") instead of first?

Comment: @Catija That could work well! I guess I put it beneath the "Stack Overflow" link only because I'm used to seeing it located like that in the site switcher, but after help could make more sense in this vertical layout. Plus on other sites like Meta there *isn't* a link for the site name itself, so that'd make even more sense down the bottom under help on those.

Answer (score 24):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) - Make the horizontal scroll bar optional. In other words, option for enabling and disabling responsiveness.

There have been concerns from users with high resolution monitors [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310934/357396), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310920/357396) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310916/357396). My answer is from point of view from a low resolution.

#### Space taken by Q&A is reduced

In one of the previous posts, [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/357396) Joe Friend has explained this responsive design is a result of long [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344521/9379355) from users having low resolution devices. There is also a statement in the question

> This benefits people who have lower resolution devices or like to have multiple windows in view.

But in practice, it is not benefiting. There are some issues.

I use a device with low resolution (1024x768). This is how it looks to me.

[image: Meta StackOverflow home page with nav bar enabled]

The right side bar is squeezed into a single window which makes the content (Q&A) sandwiched between left navigation bar and right side bar. They take very less space. The new responsive design fits everything in a single window. This squeezed  As a result, the space taken by the right side bar didn't change but the **space occupied by Q&A on the screen has decreased**.

In the current design, the main focus is on Q&A. We can scroll with the help of horizontal scroll bar the missed part in the right side bar. The space taken by Q&A is not affected at all. So, that should be continued. At least there should be an option to select it.

The look of the question is also damaged. If the question is edited by a user other than OP, the editor's avatar and OP's avatar shows in vertically rather than side by side.

[image: question with left bar enabled]

Only option we have to avoid this is to disable navigation bar.  In a previous post entitled [Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/357396), you wrote,

> We are committed to the left nav, but based on your feedback we'll be addressing some key concerns.

If the bar is always disabled, it is as good as not having it at all. If this left nav is only limited to users with high resolution devices, the goal of having a nav bar is not achieved. I hope having horizontal scroll bar will solve this problem.

#### More problems with right side bar:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
When the left navigation bar is enabled, users are not be able to comment properly. "Add comment" overlaps with the Hot Network questions.

[image: Bug showing comment dialogue box with left bar enabled]

We all are humans (well, most of us), we make mistakes. If we click on any o Hot Network question mistakenly while clicking on "Add comment", it takes us to a different site. We should get back to the comment and write it again. It is a waste of time. Not only it's an issue of time management, it doesn't good.

[image: Bug showing comment dialogue box without nav bar]

This effect can be minimized to some extent if the navigation bar is disabled. But there is an overlap of "Add comment" with the Hot question bar. Add comment button touches the site icons in Hot Network Questions. It doesn't look good.

From 1024x768 resolution screen, Browser: Firefox updated version. Also reproduced with Google Chrome updated version OS: Windows 7

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) We still have a scroll bar in the profile page in the new responsive design just like the old design.

[image: image with scroll bar on Meta StackOverflow]

Some user reported it as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but that should not be removed. I request that sort of behavior for the devices with low resolution. Users with higher resolution do not see this scroll bar at all as the current design and responsive design fits within a single window. So, there would not be a problem for them. It will be helpful for us.

Regarding sticky Topbar, it is an excellent choice.

The left navigation bar is almost empty. It would be great if more options are added into it. Home and Questions are the ones many visit. **Add more frequently visited options in the left navigation bar**.

That's all from me at the moment.

Comment: #1 There is a temporary way to turn off responsiveness. (see post above). We will be removing that at some point, however we can consider adjusting the breakpoints where the right sidebar is removed, but will probably wait for a bit for more feedback.

Comment: #2 commenting problem is a bug and we will look into that one.

Comment: #3 lack of responsiveness on some pages is an acknowledged issue. This is a work in progress. Pages that are responsive will get better (like fixing the bug above. New pages will become responsive.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this 10 times! I use a window size of 900px most of the time, and I liked having the Hot Network Questions and such off the edge of the screen, leaving more space for the main content. When I wanted to see them, I'd just scroll over.

Comment: @JoeFriend Both the requests are [status-completed].  I didn't understand why you only added that tag to bug report. I notice that this is completed for feature request too.

Answer (score 23):

[rant](/questions/tagged/rant)

I use a vertical display for my browser (so 1080 px wide), see screenshot for the aspect of SO in my browser.

While wide margins are probably fine on wide displays, here the amount of margins on both sides really reduces (and vertically squeezes) any content, to the point that only about 30% of the screen is used - that feels like a waste. I'll definitely disable the left navigation, but if you want the website to be responsive, I'd recommend to start removing margins at wider displays than now.

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) user cards next to each other.

I think there is somewhat of a misconception around responsiveness. Just making things more vertical doesn't make necessarily make them better on a less wide screen. What you want is wider content, better use of space.

On the same screenshot, you can see that the editor usercard is now vertically stacked with the author usercard. This wastes even more space, even though there is more than enough space to fit them horizontally. And again, this is a copious waste of space.

[image: SO on 1080x1920 display]

Comment: Not only is it a waste of space — it's actively misleading. I _keep_ thinking the editor is the author on first glance, and I theoretically know better by now.

Answer (score 22):

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
>
> There are some coming features that need the extra space, so we can't make it more narrow. Making adjustable is complex and we won't be doing that at this time.

**Can we narrow the right column in smaller viewports without removing it entirely?**

Below around 800px the right column moves to the bottom of the page, which is good for phones but loses some important information (question stats, professional disclaimer, community bulletin).  As soon as the right column appears, though, it grabs something like 300-320px of width.  If that kicks in at about 800 px, that's around 40% of the width, which is too large a proportion for a page that should be focused on the Q&A.  I'm browsing at about 1100px right now and it still looks a little greedy.  All of this is with the left nav already collapsed, to be clear.

*Most* of this content would fit just fine at a smaller width; mostly it's text and that can wrap.  In fact, it worked fine at, if I recall correctly, 220px for years before being widened to accommodate standard ad sizes.  On sites without this change, part of my right column is behind a scrollbar and that's fine; it's lower-priority content, after all.  But responsive design *means* "make it all fit, no horizontal scrolling".

I don't begrudge the ads; in fact, I look at them (or, on sites that don't yet have this change, most of the width of them and I'll scroll if it's something I haven't seen before).  But I'd like the right column to be less dominant on smaller viewports.  Is there some way to meet both needs?  Is there some place to put the ads so that they're fully visible without claiming that *entire* slice of vertical space?  Do we have the option to change the width of the column partway down, so that after the ad we can shrink HNQ and give Q&A more space?  I'm just brainstorming here, not proposing a specific solution.

Comment: I opened this question looking for an answer like this. I have a second monitor in vertical/portrait orientation for the express purpose of viewing long things like SO posts (and other web pages and docs). The addition of the left nav makes the width of the actual content comically small.

Comment: @JoeFriend, sorry to hear that (declined) -- I was really hoping we could do something to allow Q&A to have a larger slice of smaller screens.  I was traveling last week with a tablet, and boy was that narrow.

Comment: Speaking of wrong measures, the right column should be around 40 ens, and not adjustable at all except that it should disappear in super tiny viewports. Our measures (line lengths) are wrong nearly everywhere. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315025/153355), where I have taken your name but hopefully not in vain. :)

Answer (score 21):

I don't like the enormous amount of space at the top of the Question list pages ([home page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) and [/questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions)).

[image: old version]

vs

[image: new version]

I use a 19" monitor for my normal browsing, and on that size, that's pushing the questions even further down the page.

I could see splitting it up like it is as the width of the page gets smaller, but at full width, that's a lot of unused space. The original mockup is below, but it's missing tabs.

[image: original new left nav]

Comment: I suspect this change had something to do with teams, but I can't see teams, so maybe i'm missing some information.

Comment: FWIW Custom tag filter tabs are purported to be coming in mid-to-late June/Early July per Joe's latest post to the pinned TeamDAG MSE question. The layout here will likely change to accommodate that.

Comment: Needz more free hand red linez

Answer (score 20):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When editing a question at certain viewport sizes, the textboxes for the title, edit summary, and tags extend into the sidebar. This also happens for the edit summary when editing answers. See screenshot below.

[image: Editing a question]

Answer (score 19):

The new left navigation on Stack Overflow seems to be over-complicated due to Teams, despite not being a Teams user. The "Stack Overflow" link below "PUBLIC" actually takes you to `/questions`. Shouldn't it be called "All Questions" instead, otherwise you have two "Stack Overflow" links on the same page that take you to different pages?

Finally, I was informed in [another MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311184/335816) that the SO link with the globe icon is actually at a higher indentation level than Tags, Users and Jobs. The globe icon makes them look to be at the same level of indentation. Is it necessary?

[image: SO left nav]

As a non-Teams user, I would love the simplified look of this example I have created:

[image: SO left nav without Teams]

Or even the following to keep the public/teams separation if absolutely necessary:

[image: SO left nav simplified]

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The voting buttons on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) **don't fit to the site design's individual colour palette**. Whereas they previously were light blue, as fitting to MSE's colour palette, they now seem to use the orange from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)'s design:

[image]

I know their shape has been unified to the default arrow in an effort to standardize the sites' theming. However, the colour mismtach is rather unpleasant since it is in **stark contrast to the rest of the site's visual impression**.

This has been brought up in [previous feedback iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309608/162011), but it had been hinted that at least the button's colour would be based on the sites' existing design and themes. So maybe this is just a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: The idea with the new themes is to make them all based around a "primary color", which on MSE is the header/button blue. I'm not sure if we were going to use it for the vote buttons or not off the top of my head... but I'll check once the designer is back from a conference he's at until tomorrow.

Comment: +1 for using a **blue** freehand circle to really drive the point home :)

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build (at least in browsers that support CSS filters, so IE11 keeps orange buttons). Eventually we want to move away from sprites in favor of SVGs for the voting arrows, in which case that's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

On mobile (iOS Safari), the [/review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review) is already responsive, but there's something wrong with the achievements dialog: Teams icons are not shown in the daily summary, and the spacing/padding/alignment of the items is off as well:

[image]

This is how it looks like on desktop:

[image]

Comment: What iOS / Safari version are you using?

Comment: @balpha the newest (iOS 11.4 + built-in Safari)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it looks like expected here. Two things: 1) Is it possible that this was a network hickup? Your screenshot looks roughly like I'd expect things to look if certain CSS files weren't loaded. 2) You're specifically calling out the `/review` page -- does that mean you're only seeing this on that particular page, or was that just the page you happen to notice it on?

Comment: I can reproduce it on others pages as well, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/. I can't rule out that a CSS page has not been loaded, but I would not expect such an issue to persist for almost three weeks. I've already cleared the cache for stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, cloudflare.com, sstatic.net; should I try more? I'm using an iPhone 7 Plus, maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: So I've tried iOS 11 on iPad, iOS 10 on iPhone 7 plus, and iOS 11 on iPhone 6, and it looked like expected everywhere. I realize that that doesn't include your particular combination (I'm just going by what browserstack offers), but it seems unlikely that that would change anything. Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah, weird. I've tried Safari remote debugging but that hides the top bar entirely, so I can't figure out what's wrong either. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 16):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> completed the fixed part of this, scrolling coming soon. [Left nav is now sticky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311600/left-nav-is-now-sticky)

I'm not a fan of the left nav, but I love the way that YouTube does it: http://youtube.com.

Two things that make it great:

1. It actually hugs the extreme left side of the window, preserving space for content.
2. The left nav is **fixed** and can be scrolled **independently** of the main content.

So if we got to have a left nav, might I suggest that you just straight-up copy YouTube's design? That would be great IMO.

**One thing to note about YouTube's design** is that if you resize the window, you will notice that the left nav collapses very easily. It allows for a LOT more space for content than the responsive design here. I think that is a complaint that many people have made so far.

It just feels too squished with the left nav AND right sidebar. I think the left nav should collapse BEFORE it even affects the old max-width. So you should really only see it if you have the whitespace there to accommodate it (for example, if you are on widescreen monitor and the window is maximized, which is fairly common). But if not, it should be collapsed.

Answer (score 15):

Let me be brutally honest, I much rather the current site.

First, (I do not use SE on mobile, however) how is left-nav more mobile friendly?

Secondly, how is left-nav a better user experience? Even if the menu does not scroll?

Answer (score 15):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I don't know much about <strike>history</strike> web design, or whether "responsive" is equivalent to "the user shouldn't have to scroll to the right or zoom out". But I don't like this change.

This (screenshot is at 30%) is readable on my phone held at a typical distance, being one to one and a half feet from my face:

[image: show me the texts]

But alas, that's the Desktop view of my mobile browser (Firefox), which has its own problems.

And I can't zoom out any further. On mobile it looks like this:

[image: newline ALL the things]

And I can't zoom out again. I can read this very clearly at, I kid you not, at one and a half meter (that's about five Freedom Units) distance from my phone.

The feature request: please don't do responsive like this. Let me zoom out to get more text on my screen.

Comment: You must have exceptionally good eyes (and a very high DPI screen) for the "readable on my phone" screenshot to be readable.

Comment: @Nicol thanks, I guess! I have a resolution of 1440x2960 on 5.8", which makes a DPI of 568.

Comment: They could just make the text size smaller for mobile. Is that all you are looking for? What you said earlier (asking if responsive design means the user shouldn't zoom out or scroll) is accurate. The whole idea is everything should be presented to you without having to zoom out or pan (like a mobile app). So they can't really **not** do responsive design like this since that is what responsive design is. So maybe you want to say: don't do responsive design at all? Also, they said in the post that they haven't fully optimized the design for mobile.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I visited Stack Overflow on my tablet for the first time, and was met with this:

[image]

Not exactly the world's most welcoming landing page, is it? And yes, as others have noted, it's readable from a distance of about six feet on a seven-inch tablet.

Comment: yuck, I thought they got rid of that banner.

Comment: Yep. We are working on a fix. To reduce it's size on smaller viewports. Sorry for that.

Comment: Well, I suppose a banner that only takes up half the screen is better than one that takes up the *entire* screen, but there's still only room for two questions above the fold when I visit the site for the first time.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The bottom of tag pages is a bit clunky on small viewports – the "legend" and the "tag synonym" links might benefit from a line break between them:

> [image: Legend vs. tag synonyms]

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sure there is quite a bit of "clunky" for us to clean up for small viewports. Keep pointing things out as you see them.

Comment: @JoeFriend so it's [tag:status-planned]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess, though I have no idea how/when we will actually change it. There is a long tail of clean up.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What URL can I go to for repro?

Comment: @JoeFriend For example, [MSE tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) with a window 640px.  Shrink it more and it will eventually look like my screenshot.

Comment: @Nathaniel Got it.

Answer (score 14):

## Userscript to move the left-sidebar into the topbar network-wide <sub><sup>( [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/7928/29529) ) ( [install](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/raw/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js) ) ( [GitHub](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/blob/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js) )</sup></sub>

Because I [*really* don't like the space wasted by the left-sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307866/271271), I created [Left-sidebar in the Topbar](https://stackapps.com/q/7928/29529), which moves the left-sidebar into the topbar on all SE sites which have the left-sidebar, regardless of the preference set on each individual site. Installing this userscript is equivalent to having selecting a SE network-wide preference to "Hide left navigation". You will not need to set the preference on each individual site.

Comment: Great! You can also put your answer on [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311197) for greater visibility.

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Can we please have the right widget collapsible? Not via a checkbox in preferences, but with a button near it (you know, splitter panel style).

I like to have 2 windows open on a FullHD monitor, snapped to half of the screen each, and the site looks bogus when you disable the left nav bar - a huge chunk of vertical space is eaten up by the right widget with hot questions and related posts. I'd like to be able to collapse it, and not rely on automatic windows width-based layout auto-adjustment logic.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Also, the profile page doesn't auto-adjust itself to fit the window at half-FullHD width. There's way too much horizontal scroll to take it seriously as it is now.

Comment: Responsiveness is a work in progress and is not working for all pages (profile pages are specifically called out in a previous post that is linked to above). We will continue to improve and add responsiveness in the coming months. There are a lot of pages. Up to this point we have focused on the 20% of pages that people access 80% of the time (percentages are product manager estimates and are not to be taken literally).

Comment: @JoeFriend So we can expect the other 80% of pages to be responsive in 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: _Can we please have the right widget collapsible_ I like this idea a lot. The user should be in more control over how their space is used on their screen. As such, I've added the ability to do this via the Com branch (Which will be being pushed to master soon) in my [VisualCrumbs](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/tree/com) userscript. With this userscript enabled, you'll get a button in the left nav-bar to toggle the right sidebar, which will persist across page loads until you retoggle it.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton idk about any other parts of that script but if you could make a separate collapsible toggle thingie script and post it on stackapps, that'd be the best

Comment: @user1306322 Sure I can do that. I also plan on adding the ability to choose which features you want with VisualCrumbs. Give me a bit and I'll post up a sidebar toggler.

Comment: @user1306322 Done. https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/369524-stackoverflow-right-sidebar-toggler

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton oh so it adds a button-link to the left nav but if you have it disabled, does nothing? I thought you meant like a collapsible vertical bar on the right like in side panel controls/containers. I'm not planning on having the left nav bar enabled on any site ever, so as it is now this script does nothing for me I guess

Comment: @user1306322 The button would to toggle the sidebar would be pretty trivial to move, I put it where I did for a couple of reasons. 1) I assume the sidebar is here to stay and will be the default and only option in the future, 2) I originally had the button right above the sidebar, but the way the page renders when the sidebar was hidden then that button would be moved to the very bottom of the page. I couldn't leave it at the top with the sidebar collapsed because it would really just hide the content of the sidebar and leave the whitespace the same.

Comment: Alright, well, it's a script that works for the use case you've described. It's not just what I personally wanted, which is okay. If I need, I'll write one that I like :p You can post yours on StackApps.com to give it more visibility among SE/SO users if you wish.

Comment: @user1306322 I've already got visualcrumbs on there.

Answer (score 13):

All of this is unnecessary. The white space reserved for the left nav keeps stealing screen real state long after the left nav is no longer in sight. Why? Why do you think that this is needed? SO has many problems but the UI it's not really one of them (until you go and change it and *make it* a problem).

Btw, "Hide navigation" it's not working for me.

Comment: Agree, the content part is far too small. It's hard to actually read questions even on large screens now. Most of the space is taken up by the side bars and pointless white space.

Comment: @James *"It's hard to actually read questions even on large screens now"* - I wonder what version of SE you used before, seeing how the width of the main content didn't change *at all*. They basically just filled some of the white space that was *already there* with content.

Comment: It was definitely squashing it for me. Finally got the setting to work and it seems to have opened up some space.

Comment: Try printing out an SO Q+A then.....this responsiveness design....even with the left navigation side-panel turned off....leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 13):

One thing not yet mentioned in the other answers is the inclusion of the `+ Create Team` link.

[image: new SO menu]

As a user that has no intention of subscribing to the Teams feature, this is just noise.

If at some time I do decide to subscribe I would make a conscious effort to seek out the sign-up page. Having this  displayed front and center on every page seems a bit desperate.

Comment: I doubt they are goin to remove it. This is the latest money-making machine.

Comment: You could always set up a custom filter on an add blocker to hide it.

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

*Posting feature-request/bug from comment*:

Can you please add the tabination to the about-tag-page?

On every other tag page you see this tabination:

[image]

On the about-tag-page is no tabination:

[image]

This means that you are basically trapped from the info page and unable to return to the question page unless you figure out to click on the tag itself. This is (in my opinion) kind of unintuitive

---

Oh and this behaviour is new. Picture from SO:

[image: PHP]

Answer (score 12):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

OK, this is just ridiculous. Can you lower the vertical space wastage? Or just remove it altogether? Nobody really needs >20% of their viewing height to be taken up by this:

[image: Screenshot]

You could e.g. literally cut it in half just by moving the bottom row into the middle of the top row.

Comment: There is content in that "blank" space in most question list views. ([see example](https://cl.ly/2M1e0Q2w3y04/Image%202018-06-12%20at%2012.14.20%20PM.png))

Comment: Content that used to exist in the right column instead

Comment: @JoeFriend: Good point, but in all honesty while I realize you guys care about this, I (and I assume most users) couldn't care less how many questions there are with no answers. We answer what we can, and that's that. Also, you could definitely still shrink it even with that content with some more creativity. You could even also just move that additional text to the left column to avoid it taking up space altogether. Vertical space is far more scarce than horizontal.

Comment: @JoeFriend: Actually you guys could probably remove that section altogether. You could put the `Top Questions` on the left nav, shrink the Search box a bit, and put the buttons on the top bar, or maybe utilize the right side somehow.

Comment: White space does actually help make a page more readable. I think that the consistency of placement is more valuable than getting rid of a little white space.

Comment: Move *Ask Question* to left bar, more space available for tightening the top part

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

After checked the "Hide left navigation" option in the [preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), the Meta Stack Exchange site header container is not aligned with it's top and bottom div.

Can be the `<img src` add with some spacing to align with the top and bottom divs when hide the left navigation.

**Current behavior:**

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange site header container]

**Expected behavior:**

> [image: Expected]

Comment: Yes, this is bad.  [It lines up neatly with left nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6oHs.png), but [sticks out to the left with left nav disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yN9e.png).

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I had to disable the left nav bar on both SO and this Meta.

Does this setting really need to be on a per-site basis? Can't it be that disabling the nav bar is a global setting accross the whole network?

Comment: As stated by Joe Friend, it is [under consideration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311197/checkbox-doesnt-disable-left-nav/311199#311199).

Comment: @NogShine OK. I checked this thread for duplicates but failed to search meta for similar questions.

Comment: [Userscript to do the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311268)

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> see [Left nav is now sticky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311600/left-nav-is-now-sticky)

Can we have an option to make the new sidebar sticky?

Not Sticky:

[image]

VS Sticky:

[image]

Comment: This is included in my userscript [VisualCrumbs](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/tree/com) in the Com branch which I will be pushing to the master shortly.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I understand that the new design may be good and necessary for some users, but it is really annoying for me, whatever my settings, to have to either press the menu button or to scroll to the top of the page before I can press of questions, tags or users.

Could we have a preference option to get back the old top bar, please?

---

Edit:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> brings up a list of keyboard shortcuts including ones to above-mentioned places, however, new users may not know this and it is not as convenient as the top bar:
[image: The Shift+G list]

Comment: "Home" is directly accessible via the logo, they're all accessible via shift+g+h, q, t, and u

Comment: @KevinB Apart from home, those are still much less convenient than before, and new users won't know that (like me!).

Comment: I don't disagree, just pointing out shortcuts do exist. I particular like shift+g+m

Comment: @KevinB What does that do?

Comment: It swaps back and forth between the main site and its meta.

Comment: I posted this above, but you can use Stylish or other similar addons to add this style to MSO: `#left-sidebar nav[role="navigation"] { position: sticky; top: 75px; }` on browsers that support `position: sticky;`. It will cause the list of links (home, questions, tags, users) to scroll with you.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl We won't be supporting the left nav OR navigation in the top bar as a user setting. Navigation is moving to the left bar across the network. If you have an alternate proposal to address your concerns I'd be interested in hearing it..

Comment: @JoeFriend my next best option would be point 2 of Andre Kool's post, ([tag:status-deferred]), which points out that you have to scroll up. (The menu should scroll with the page)

Comment: @ArtemisFowl This is [tag:status-completed], isn't it?

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

The top icons - inbox, achievements, review, etc are overflowing. I have to side scroll to see them.

Screenshot:

[image]

This is on mobile. Samsung Galaxy Trend S-75whatever, Chrome, Android 4.2.2.

Comment: As mentioned above. We have not fully optimized for all mobile screens and doing so will take some time. It almost works on SO.com (depending on your device), but the SE logo needs changes for it to work on MSE. Feel free to continue to use the mobile skin until we get to this.

Comment: My [answer written June 6th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310939/282094) discusses the failings of mobile desktop view with TylerH, whom has looked into this.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When not logged in, the banner here on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) has z-index issues, it hides the popup menus:

> [image]
>   [image]

(Easiest way to reproduce is browsing in private/guest mode)

Comment: This types of bug must be tested before push the update to live site. Specially from big companies like StackOverflow

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The [ability to have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) "Disable top bar stickiness" unchecked and  "Hide left navigation" checked is a wonderful feature. It keeps things similar to the way they are now.

With all the space freed up we have room to bring back the Rep to the top bar's avatar. This currently doesn't work for mobile devices with a high pixel density. On my Galaxy S9 with a reported resolution of 2768x1440, I see this in Firefox Mobile:

[image: Screenshot of Firefox]

---

A possible workaround for large tablets - probably not desirable for a mobile phone:

- Go to Settings and set your Font size to huge.
- Go to "Developer Options", or use the 'Search Bar' and type "minimum".
- Set the "Minimum Width" to 980.

The result on a **mobile phone** is difficult to use; but the StackExchange site shows your Avatar, Reputation, and Badges (the same as a few months ago).

On a **large tablet** it might be OK (untested) but on a phone the keyboard is especially tiny (could probably adjust that in the APP) and other APPs may appear different.

The phone's UI doesn't expect this and things are tiny with incorrect spacing. Many things don't look very good, I set it back the way it was and will simply visit my SE Profile if I'm curious while we wait for this to be fixed. Probably not useful on a phone, someone whom is eagle eyed might prefer this.

I thought I'd mention this in case it helps someone.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like, and the Setting screens:

[image: Funky Fix]

Comment: Reputation and badges are already visible next to the avatar in the top bar if the resolution is high enough. It disappears when your browser window is 980px wide or smaller.

Comment: Incorrect. It disappears on my 2960x1440 screen, it was visible on my screen a few months ago.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that - on Firefox 60 in Windows it shows up just fine at 2960x1440 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzlGN.png What browser are you using and are you sure you do not have any other userscripts? Can you provide a screenshot at that resolution with the reputation missing?

Comment: Using Android. I don't see it and had three UpVotes a minute ago ... Here are two browsers I've tested: Google Chrome: 67.0.3396.68, Firefox: 61.0b11 - adding cropped screenshot of the upper right to the answer.

Comment: @Rob Using Android? What device are you using? A tablet of some kind? It's likely a poorly-formed media query detecting device type rather than screen-size. Based on that screenshot it looks like you are on a device with like, 400px, not 2960px, so it could be a problem between actual pixels and device pixels.

Comment: The CSS there appears to be from primary.css: `@screen and (max-width: 980px) { .top-bar .my-profile .-rep { display: none; } }` so your device is apparently reporting that it is 980px wide or less.

Comment: @TylerH - I have a Samsung Galaxy S9+ running Oreo. This webpage: https://web.basemark.com/ reports my screen size as: 1440x2768 -- **many** (I've been looking for a couple of hours) other websites, such as [BrowserSpy](http://browserspy.dk/screen.php), incorrectly report my screen size as: Width 360, Height 692, AvailHeight 692, AvailWidth 360 . (or other ridiculously small numbers) -- I'm attempting to locate a webpage with a 'Test Button' and code that *just works* and reports the correct value. The value at basemark is close enough but not exact.I'll report back later today with something?

Comment: @Rob Yeah, the S9 goes up to 1440px wide and is supposed to be at least 1080px wide out of the box, so unless you have manually set your resolution to something lower, my guess is we are running into an issue [where a pixel is not a pixel](https://juiceboxinteractive.com/ideas/a-pixel-is-not-a-pixel-designing-new-generation-mobile-devices/). See also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863545/physical-pixels-vs-css-pixels-vs-device-independent-pixels-vs-density-independen).

Comment: See also http://vizdevices.yesviz.com/article.php - looks like your web browser viewport is effectively 740 "real" pixels as far as the media queries are designed. http://vizdevices.yesviz.com/devices/s9/

Comment: @TylerH - Great links. The website: http://vizdevices.yesviz.com/mydevice.php reports: My Device - width (Visible Area) 360px, height (Visible Area) 668px, device-width (Viewport) 360px, device-height (Viewport) 692px, device-pixel-ratio 4, device-resolution-width 1440px, device-resolution-height 2768px - the last 2 values would be OK. The second link lists: Resolution 1440x2960 PX, Viewport Size 360x740  PX. [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?answertab=votes#tab-top). Thanks for looking into this. PS: YouTube is another site that's 1440 for me.

Comment: @TylerH - A minute ago this was partially fixed on Meta.SE, but now it's back to not fixed. I guess someone is testing. It only showed the Rep and not the badges.

Comment: Another [report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188628/282094) (fixed) of screen size causing a problem with the rendering of the webpages.

Answer (score 10):

Now that this is live, and I can't turn it off, I'll repeat my earlier disappointments.  The left nav bar takes up entirely too much real estate for mostly useless links.  I thought hiding the bar would help things, and now that it's live, I can see some problems with the approach.

*Most* of the left nav links are infrequently used.  The "Questions" link, however, is probably my *MOST* frequently used link, and making that a two step process is really annoying.

Also, the "opt-out" for hiding the menu, and turning it into a hamburger, is sort of a secret.  How is a new user supposed to know about this??  Even if a new user figures it out, the links that live under the hamburger are a mystery!!  There isn't even a drop down on mouseover that would give someone not in on how the page works a clue about what's under there. A user **should not** have to know how a web site works to figure out how to use it.

So, where does that leave us??  I feel like I'm working with a UI that's significantly less functional than that UI I used to have.  I'm not a web person, so I can't even pretend to understand (or, frankly, care) why the change was necessary.

The amazing thing is that just about all of the flaws were pointed out after about two minutes of beta!!  This stuff should have been dealt with, instead of simply badly patched.  It demonstrates not just a difference of opinions, but poor process.

As a last note, I'll add that this is SE, and the people here have a reputation of knowing what they're doing.  I can't help but feel that a backward step like this **hurts the brand.**

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Due to Teams/Channels the left sidebar menu on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is already a little different from the rest of the sites (with [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) currently being the only available example). But a significant difference that sticks out is that **SO doesn't seem to have an "Unanswered" menu item**, while MSE does:

[image]

This seems **unrelated to Teams/Channels** and thus seems to be an inconsistency in a UI overhaul that strives to largely **unify the experience** on the various SE sites.

Comment: This inconsistency was already in the design. We have plans to make it consistent, but it is dependent on changes we are working on around filters/sorts for question lists. Coming soon. ;)

Answer (score 9):

The left pane adds very little to the functionality of the site, but it takes away much.

- SO design thus far has had a **airy, open** design. This left nav
  (especially the border line running through the page top to bottom)
  makes for a claustrophobic feel, and content **feels quite boxed in**.
- The Nav links were far functional at the top of the page. **The teams could have very well been placed up there in the top nav as a dropdown.**
- Symmetry has taken a hit with the left panel being much different than the right panel

[image]

Two questions with regard to the Teams menu:

1. Do you expect that users will have a long list of teams?
2. Does a user keep looking at the list of teams always even though only one is maybe selected right now?

Comment: This made me think that teams should have been in the SE community menu.

Comment: Not sure what is "taken away". Also, there are plans to add more functionality to the left sidebar such as saved searches or moving favorite tags. Right now it's not "finalized" so consider seeing the info posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps?noredirect=1&lq=1) that talks about future plans for the left sidebar.

Comment: 1st and 3rd points say what is taken away. The left border makes it boxy and restricted. Symmetry is gone because of the left border. And, atleast on the home page, there is no spacing on the left between the questions and the left nav. Also, the left nav is so thin... its gonna get horizontal scroll or ellipsis for some items for sure.

Answer (score 9):

Minor styling bug that I don't think anyone mentioned:

[image]

This was taken at 1000px x 676px. On question pages that have the "x questions" text, the row of buttons overlaps the featured box if the window is nearly at the point where the responsive style switches, but not quite there.

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party but now as the theme went live on my favorite site (Ask Ubuntu) there are issues beyond of what I feared.

Often I have to work on small screens (office computer, netbook) where not much space for content is left if we deduce all windows decorations, top bars, bottom bars, side bars, and whatnot from the visible are:

[image]

This was already an issue with the old design but it sadly could not be improved with the new theme. **The left side menu is a great thing.** I like it a lot but it needs to hold many more items than now. Much of the top bar items could reside there.

So here are my suggestions for great improvements that could be achieved with only very little changes to the overall site design:

- Move the broad top bar with the site logo to the side menu to **keep it sticky** so that we still know on which site we are when scrolling down through questions.
- Leave **Beta** on the non-sticky colored top bar which would move away on scrolling to have the site logo small enough to fit the side menu.
- <kbd>Newest, Featured, Frequent...</kbd> go to a submenu on the "Questions" side menu entry. Even a dropdown could be considered there.
- The <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button moves to the side menu where it would be sticky too. A good place appears to be e.g. directly under the site logo. By this the Ask button is accessible from everywhere.
- The question count goes to the title where **All** needs to be replaced by the display options we chose (e.g. *Active, Newest, Unanswered*)

To illustrate all this better here are screenshots from only few changes needed to the source:

[image]
Landing Page for Active Questions display

[image]
Same page scrolled down

An additional minor improvement was moving the search field a bit to the right to better align with the left side menu.

Answer (score 9):

### On mobile, username and picture of editors shown before authors, making it easy to assume wrong author if you don't look closely.

Example:

[image: screenshopt]

---

If you just skim and don't carefully look for "edited" or "answered", it's easy to assume that the first person listed is the one primarily associated with the answer. This should probably go the other way around.

I *keep* making this mistake both on questions and answers. I think this is a significant usability problem. We already have some confusion over this with new users mistaking the editor for the author — now we're going to have that for *everyone*.

Simply swapping the two would be a big help, but I think it should go even further — maybe don't show the user pic for the editor, or make it smaller somehow.

Comment: Update: I've not grown used to it. I am still fooled constantly. Arghhhhghh!

Answer (score 7):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

The "Ask Question" button now has a red border, red text and changes its background color to red when hovered over.

I find this a little irritating because I associate red buttons with actions I should be thinking over twice before executing them because they may have dangerous effects (which asking a question is not, in my opinion).

Is this on purpose so users think twice before they click this button? Or is there an other reason for the color change? I somehow liked the old black better and would like to know the reason for the change.

Comment: "I find this a little irritating because I associate red buttons with *actions I should be thinking over twice before executing them*" that's a good thing. If you just run around asking every question you come up with without doing proper research or providing proper information, etc, you can find yourself question banned rather quickly. Asking a question should be the last resort.

Comment: [I too support this subtle "think twice before asking" cue.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6979250#6979250)

Comment: On a site that calls itself a question and answers site, asking questions is apparently enough of a problem that you need to think twice before doing so ... and this is apparently a good thing. Wow!

Answer (score 7):

## Measure for measure, we’re much too long

#### SUMMARY

> > We’re in flagrant violation of [Bringhurst rule 2.1.2: *Choose a comfortable measure*](http://webtypography.net/2.1.2).

ʀᴇʟᴀᴛᴇᴅ: [Static, unchanging font size, leading, and measure incompatible with dynamics of responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316797/static-unchanging-font-size-leading-and-measure-incompatible-with-dynamics-of)

---

The desktop line measure is still **much, *much* too long**
for comfortable reading of continuous text in a variable-width
font. This is wrong on both serifed and sans sites alike.
We’re using lines 100 characters long, which is completely
unreadable except maybe in a fixed-width face.

<sup>*(And again, without manual correction.)*</sup>

The desktop line measure is still **much, *much* too long** for comfortable reading of continuous text in a
variable-width font. This is wrong on both serifed and sans sites alike. We’re using lines 100 characters long,
which is completely unreadable except maybe in a fixed-width face.

<sup>*(And again, in constant-width.)*</sup>

```
The desktop line measure is still much, much too long for comfortable reading of continuous text in a
variable-width font. This is wrong on both serifed and sans sites alike. We’re using lines 100 characters long,
which is completely unreadable except maybe in a fixed-width face.
```

Or for those of you who aren’t on the desktop site, that’s:

> [image: image of foregoing text for those stuck on a cell phonelet]

## Demonstrations of Badness

This demo from [Monica’s answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311179/153355) is a good example of
what happens with a bad measure:

#### Example 1 of way-too-long lines

> [image: example of overly long lines]

#### Example 2 of way-too-long lines

This is no better on those rare sites with a bit
of serifed text, as demonstrated by [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/244294/2085):

[image: Sven Yargs’ answer about "programing"]

## *Thus Spake Bringhurst*

In [*The Elements of Typographic Style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Typographic_Style), Robert Bringhurst writes:

> #### 2.1.2 *Choose a comfortable measure.*
>
> Anything from 45 to 75 characters is widely regarded as a satis-
> factory length of line for a single-column page set in a serifed
> text face in a text size. The 66-character line (counting both
> letters and spaces) is widely regarded as ideal. For multiple-
> column work, a better average is 40 to 50 characters.
>       If the type is well set and printed, lines of 85 or 90 charac-
> ters will pose no problem in discontinuous tests, such as bibli-
> ographies, or with generous leading, in footnotes. But even
> with generous leading, a line that averages more than 76 or 80
> characters is likely to be too long for continuous reading.

Or with serifs:

[image: repeat of Bringhurst in a serif face]

(Or course, you shouldn’t use hyphenation with a ragged margin,
but I’m trying to reproduce the book, which has a justified
right margin and thus some hyphenatinon.)

## Demonstration of Goodness

For example, the New York Times uses a 66-character line:

> [image: plum-tart recipe description from the New York Times, 2018-09-01]
>
> > **Credit**: [“A Plum Tart That Keeps Its Charms Hidden”](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/31/dining/plum-tart-recipe.html?rref=collection%2Fbyline%2Fmelissa-clark&action=click&contentCollection=undefined&region=stream&module=stream_unit&version=latest&contentPlacement=1&pgtype=collection), Melissa Clark’s
> > regular “A Good Appetite” column from the August 31, 2018
> > print edition of *The New York Times*.

## Let’s stop being so *irresponsive*

Notice how much easier the *Times’* text is to read compared
with Monica’s or Sven’s? This is because we haven’t sized
the measure correctly. In other words, this is ***irresponsive***
design, not the responsive design it’s purported to be.

The *Times* sets the font size and the measure in a way
that makes it easy to read no matter the viewport.

We don’t. We should.

Comment: One problem -- line length in characters is not constant even for the same viewport size, because some people zoom in or out.  Part of why I find the right column too aggressive on my tablet is that, in fact, it makes the lines too short for the Q&A part, because I have to use some font zoom to be able to read comfortably at all.  One size does not fit all, and one failure of responsive design is that it doesn't (and can't?) take client-side size settings into account.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I know exactly what you mean. For whatever reason (meaning, I don't understand it), very few sites manage to use a reasonable size for running text. I feel like the *Times* is one of the few sites you aren't expected to zoom any longer to read. Certainly all the SE sites are horrible about this. I feel like something has changed since it was all set up, but I don't know what.

Comment: I currently use a combination of browser zoom (which is whole-page zoom, which means horizontal scrolling at some point) and a user style to change the font sizes in the places that matter most.  It's a pain.  It seems like responsive design would simplify that -- zoom would be enough and I could drop the style -- except that the right column is really aggressive in viewports that are sized for (my) comfortable reading (or hardware max, in the case of my tablets).

Comment: I think 75 characters could be a good width for SE. But I wouldn't want images to have to be less wide than they are now. Not sure how those two could work together.

Comment: Since you're using my post as an example, let me show you [what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JGXj.png).  Looks to me like you need to adjust your font settings. :-)  And this demonstrates my point that you cannot successfully hard-wire a *pixel width* to get a desired *character count*.

Answer (score 7):

Cross-posted from [Arqade's theming rollout](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13119/28182) upon request:

---

Is the old mobile site slated to be replaced by the responsive design any time soon? Because there are a couple of things I noticed when switching from old mobile  to the full responsive site that are concerning

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

## 1. There's too much going on in the top bar.

May just be a symptom of having mod tools, but there is no free space on the bar, no clear separation of areas. **Could we maybe drop or combine some functionality here at mobile widths?** For example:

- Drop or combine the SE logo content box into the site switcher or left-nav dropdown, and/or
- Combine the diamond and the blue flag notification, and/or
- Combine everything into Left nav except search, main (red) notifications and the site switcher

[image: Top bar]

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## 2. The tag page 'Learn More' etc links get squished:

Can this wrap to another line instead?

[image: Tag Page on mobile]

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

## 3. The question title text is too big on long questions

Potentially reduce the font size at mobile widths?

[image: Long Question title]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When I hover over the other menu items there's a hover effect, making the background gray

[image: showing hover in site selection]

**edit**
In the new menu there's only a very slight font color change, that I had to change my monitor settings for to be able to visually notice.

[image]

Could a hover effect be added?

Note, this is in the hamburger menu view.

Please make the hover effect consistent with the other hamburger menus by adding a background color change on hover.

Comment: I actually do have a hover effect, although it is very slight. The text of the hovered item goes bold.- https://imgur.com/DXHIiIP

Comment: @GPPK The text doesn't go bold. It changes color. To be exact, it goes from #535a60 to #0C0D0E, which is a very subtle change.

Comment: well on my monitor I don't even see that color change. Be consistent with the other menu's and add a colored background. Or remove the colored background with the other menus. Inconsistent behavior is messy.

Comment: Fiddled a bit with the monitor settings, now I can see it however so slight.

Answer (score 6):

The "unanswered" page of any tag, e.g. `c#`, doesn't contain the tag definition part.

**Newest `c#`**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&pageSize=50

[image]

**Unanswered `c#`**
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23

[image]

The tab changes from

info | newest | featured | frequent | votes | active | unanswered

to

(all Questions) | my tags | newest | votes | no answers | all questions

- Why twice the "all questions"?
- Why are "featured", "frequent" and "active" gone?
- Why is only on unanswered the "my tags" visible?
- Why did "unanswered" get renamed to "no answers"?

The number of questions isn't displayed consistently:

**Newest (without tag)**
[image]

**Unanswered (without tag)**
[image]

**Newest `c#`**
[image]

**Unanswered `c#`**
[image]

Why does https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest (and all other tabs, besides "unanswered") have two ways to go to "unanswered" the item in the tab and the separate button "Answer questions"?
[image]

Because of this (I assume) there is also a rather unpleasant jump when switching around the tabs since the "unanswered" page doesn't have that button.

Comment: The state of the "unanswered" pages is more or less a disaster and has been for a while. Thankfully, it's unrelated to the theming changes. :) Or at least it should be. The tag definition part is up in the search bar for some reason, but it's there.

Comment: @AdamLear edited my "answer" - not sure what you mean with `The tag definition part is up in the search bar for some reason, but it's there.` - you mean invisible for the human eye? cant see it

Comment: I mean this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W07dN.png. It's not great. I agree we need to review the layout on those pages.

Comment: @AdamLear - with tag definition I meant the following highlighted part https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLYEc.png - this whole part is missing on the unanswered page - the `c#` in the searchbox is visible on all pages (newest, featured and so on) - only the "tag definition" - `C# (pronounced "C sharp") is a high level, ...` is missing

Answer (score 6):

There's a **lot** of whitespace in the top part of the page. I first noticed this on MSO, and [filed a bug there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369275/2422776), and was prompted to check out this thread by André Kool's comment there.

Not sure what's the proper etiquette here, so I'm just linking to my original post instead of re-posting here.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Is there some reason those links cannot simply be moved to the top, as in the case of other sites (such as Server Fault, in the below screenshot)?

### [image: Server Fault screenshot]

Now about the Stack Overflow page:

[image: Stack Overflow screenshot]

Do you have any statistics on how many users actually use those links in the left bar? By "use", I mean spend a reasonable amount of time on the target page, and not "oops, misclicked that, go back".

- If I had to take a guess, 99% users (and that's counting all users who access the site, not just users who log in) have no need to frequently visit "Tags", "Users", "Jobs".
- 99.9% users have no use for the "Create Team" link since clicking on that leads to a paywall, which will almost always be followed by hitting the Back button (or equivalently, closing the tab/window).

You probably don't need to put that many links in the left bar to pages that aren't frequently accessed. Of course, you have access to statistical usage data that I don't, so I hope you have already taken that into account.

Also, there is absolutely no need for **three** links to Stack Overflow on the left bar. (Although one of those links leads to stackoverflow.com/questions, but that doesn't really make much difference.) You might consider fixing that as well.

Moreover, since those links are already found at the bottom of the page, the left bar is pretty much redundant. There's also a **fourth** link to Stack Overflow there for some reason.

Comment: Why downvote? What problem do you have with this?

Comment: Another downvote! Can you please enlighten me why you need *four* links to StackOverflow on the StackOverflow page, and why you need so many rarely used links in the left nav bar? Also, why do you not want to move those links to the top as it is done for the other sites?

Comment: Because as explained in the linked meta post, that won't work with teams.

Comment: @KevinB So what about it? The majority of users don't need it.

Comment: Doesn't really change the reasoning behind doing it.

Comment: @KevinB So how does that "pay off technical debt"? Anyway, features which only 0.01% users need shouldn't feature so prominently in primary navigation. That is why I asked for statistical data to justify all those links in the left nav bar. If only 0.01% users use it, then that Teams is just noise and anyway it is already found at the bottom, so can be removed from left nav bar.

Comment: I don't disagree, and they already have plans to fix that from what i've been told in chat, the "Teams" feature will be more "context-aware", which hopefully means it we'll get the left nav from meta rather than what we currently have on SO for users who don't use teams. They'll also be adding more features to the left menu.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

One more request about the tag questions page: can we have an option to collapse the tag excerpt and related links? I know the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag excerpt by heart now, I don't need to have it occupy 25% of the screen height.

[image: Tag questions page]

Answer (score 5):

For me, when the left navigation bar is enabled, the content of the page is pushed off to the right, and a horizontal scrollbar appears. In other words, the width of the existing content to the right of the left navigation bar does not shrink in order to accommodate it.

I am using 64-bit Firefox 60.0.2 on Windows 10.

[image: Without Left Navigation Bar]
[image: With Left Navigation Bar-1]
[image: With Left Navigation Bar-2]

Comment: Ah, Now I understand. Okay, so if you read the post above in detail you'll see that not all pages have been made responsive. We've done the 20% of the pages people access 80% of the time. Profiles is definitely on the list, but it need a major overhaul to make it responsive.

Comment: Cheers! Trust me to routinely use something most people don't. ;) I use my network profile as a "dashboard" from which to open up the various sites I follow . . .

Comment: I actually think that is fairly common. We just haven't gotten around to those pages yet. As you probably well know, they are quite complex.

Answer (score 5):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

So, finally [the Badges tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/badges) have been dropped? I earlier discussed [Why do "Badges" have their own tab in the navigation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283815/260388); now I don't find the tab for Badges in new navigation. Is it dropped due to redundancy or any other spacing issue or will be added later

[image]

Comment: The badges link is in the achievements dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When you disable the left navigation menu, you see a menu icon at the left of the top bar. That icon has a right border that doesn't fit with the other elements in the top bar.

Could that border be removed?

With border:

> [image: With border]

An example without border:

> [image: Without border]

Comment: That's an extremely minor change. Is there a reason you particular want that?

Comment: @Clonkex Because every time I open StackOverflow I can't help but focus on it, I find it distracting.

Comment: It has a border and it also does not align with page contents.

Answer (score 4):

### Transformative left-nav

It would be transformative for regular users if the left-nav gave users customisation options such as by adding their own links etc., e.g. for meta, favourite chat rooms, the ability to pin questions by dragging them to there, the things they use most. Then it would become a joy to use.

Failing that it's at least be better the user has the ability to hide it, as it fills a lot of prime real estate with empty white space.  But it should be clear **on it**, that it is, by some pin or x in the corner, rather than hidden elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

**User's flags view on mobile stretches out too much**

Which is probably related to responsive mobile still being worked on, but just in case.

Chrome 69.0.3497.100 from Google Play, phone running Android 5.1.

[image: flags view stretches out]

Comment: Thanks! We still have a lot of work to do, particularly when it comes to moderation pages like this.

Comment: This isn't a mobile problem per se. It's a problem you'll see anywhere if your window is narrower than a certain amount. I'm seeing this on desktop.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Personally, I'm not a fan of the border at the right. It gives the questions a bit of a *boxed-in* look, and I think it looks nicer without it. Especially when scrolling down a lot, I think it looks nicer without a border, also because the left sidebar doesn't have one.

With:

[image]

Without:

[image]

Comment: I had this exact same concern and so I decided I'll write a userscript to hide it for myself if nobody else thinks this is a "visual feeling" issue. Guess I'm not alone. It really does feel like the air is snuffed out and the page becomes a claustraphobic cubicle

Comment: I totally agree with this. It's like an itch in my brain while it's there. I immediately created a userscript to fix it, then realised I can disable the navbar completely. I'm happy now.

Answer (score 3):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> [Hide Left nav everywhere with a global preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311528/hide-left-nav-everywhere-with-a-global-preference)

Even after changing preference. Nav bar is still there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: We've had a few mentions of this and  are investigating.

Comment: @JoeFriendok, let me know If I can do anything to help testing.

Comment: @JoeFriend Yes, I read preferences are site specifics, but how you get there? I cant find the preference button. Only the link above.

Comment: Change the url to match the site you want to go to. So, for SO it would be:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

Answer (score 3):

When I answer a question now, the width of the preview I see below the answer box is not correct. The actual answer that gets displayed when I post it will be narrower than the preview, so blocks of code may gain scroll bars that I wasn't expecting.

```
For instance, this fits on one line in the preview but it may need a scroll bar when I actually post it
```

I hope this is only a bug with the answer preview. It would be really bad if the width of all code blocks was actually changed, since that would break a ton of old answers that used to use all the width available (for things like comments at the end of lines), but now they're too wide.

Comment: While it might be more of a problem now, this was already a problem. There are various Meta posts complaining about this (at least one is relatively recent). The problem existed (and exists) with seeing a different number of characters per line in the preview vs. once it was saved. It also existed (and exists) between what was shown in different browsers. While it's certainly something that should be addressed, it's not new due to this layout.

Comment: Ah, that may well be. I only know that it didn't happen for me before (in Firefox with a maximized window width of 1080 pixels) but it always does now. The new layout may have promoted this issue from a fringe one that only affected people with unusual resolutions into something that effects almost everybody. I'll go search for and upvote the existing issue though.

Answer (score 3):

Can you make the "Hide left navigation" the default setting?

That way, users who don't login (including users who have accounts but use private browsing mode) don't have to see the left bar, and users who *want* to see it can always enable it from the settings.

Comment: Why downvote? What problem do you have with this?

Comment: I downvoted since this default amounts to making the site's primary navigation less visible, and in fact hidden unless/until they find the hamburger menu. That's not something I think we'd want. Primary navigation needs to be quite visible, especially to new users. Opting out of it being highly visible is something people would do as more advanced users who are more comfortable using the site, if they wanted to do that -- like the kinds who have figured out the site well enough to find and use the preferences menu.

Comment: @doppelgreener ... and what exactly is so "primary" about these navigation links? The only useful link (which could be frequently used by new/old user alike) I see there is "Tags", which can easily be accommodated on the top bar. There is absolutely no reason to have **two** links to SO in the left nav bar, especially when there's already one in the top left. "Users" can also be accommodated on top as it is done on ServerFault (see my [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311420/202356)).

Comment: Primary navigation means the top level of navigation you offer to people for navigating a site. [This article goes into the subject a bit](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/planning-and-implementing-website-navigation/). So... that's what's primary about it. It's the site's primary navigation and it ought not be hidden away. If you'd rather move some of the primary navigation options elsewhere like into the top bar, that's different to hiding the primary navigation by default.

Comment: @doppelgreener Sure, I do understand what primary navigation means. My claim is that this left nav bar is *not* the primary navigation. None of the links given there have anything "primary" about it. What exactly is your usecase for accessing the "Users" page for a new user? I mean for what reason do they have to go that page?

Comment: Primary navigation doesn't mean new users have to have a reason to explore every bit of it -- but it is important for them to have those links available and discoverable and not tucked away. What else is the primary navigation if not that?

Comment: @doppelgreener Primary navigation is for links to the site pages that most people are likely to use most frequently, not for features that few people will use once in a while. You should probably read the article that you shared. :) **Primary navigation stands for the content that most users are interested in.**

Comment: In summary, the left navigation bar is *not* primary navigation. It is just noise. *If* it were the primary navigation, then I would completely agree with you that it shouldn't be hidden by default.  I hope we can be in agreement now?

Answer (score 3):

I did go to left nav link and turned off left nav panel as instructed (with some difficulty). But now I can't navigate at all - my work flow is to go back to the question list after looking at a question. The back button isn't always the best way to do that.

(Perhaps this should have been a comment - perhaps it's even been discussed above and I didn't follow instructions before posting - but felt I had to vent right away.)

**Edit** with more information.

Someone kindly pinged me to tell me about the button on the upper left that gives me navigation (back to questions). Thanks.

Next beef. The question list (without the nav bar) lists hot network questions on the right, as it used to and should. But they now take up nearly half the screen width. If I increase font size (Firefox) to trade for a willingness to scroll the question font increases (good) and the hot question list disappears entirely ...

Comment: @rene It does - but see my edit.

Comment: There is a user scrip available at https://stackapps.com/q/7938/54601 which tries to bring these buttons back. The layout might need some improvement, but in general it works well.

Answer (score 3):

**Yet another whitespace issue, mobile edition**

On phones, when viewing a question, the question (and answer) bodies are indented to make room for the voting buttons to the left.  *This is not a complaint about that* -- yeah, I'd like to do better there while retaining access to the mod tools, but *this* post is about a consequence of that: comments.

In the desktop view comments are indented such that their scores (if present) align with the edge of the post body.  There's room for that in the desktop view.  On a phone, it makes lines too short in comments, which means I can view fewer comments at a time and have to scroll more.  On phones where real-estate is limited, can we please align the comments with the post body?  That'll still leave plenty of room for comment votes/flags.

[image: marked-up screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility)

Make the `#content` element a **main** landmark.

[The main landmark will help screen reader users jump straight to the main content](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/main.html). It lets screen reader users skip past header and navigation. NVDA screen reader users can for example press <kbd>D</kbd> three times to skip to the header landmark, then to the main nav landmark, then to the main content landmark.

(Not all screen reader users know about this ability, and most sites don't implement it, so this should be done in conjunction with skip links, not instead of them.)

Specifically, change it from:

- `<div id="content">`

to either one of these:

- `<div role="main" id="content">`
- `<main role="main" id="content">`

The Main element is a HTML5 semantic element, and effectively identical to `<div role="main">` so either one works fine.

Writing `<main role="main">` is something we do for IE11 compatibility. (In all other browsers it's redundant.) IE11 came out with support for the main *role* but without support for the main *element*, which it treats as unknown but stylable. See [Can I Use: HTML5 Semantic Elements](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic). If you use the main element you'll also want to add the following CSS line to your page to tell IE how to render the element: `main { display: block; }`

Answer (score 3):

**Search button overlaps right nav**

Similar to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310973/398063) about how adding a comment overlays right nav, and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311042/398063) with edits, and [yet another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311411/398063) with another set of buttons.

Firefox 62.0, Windows 10, happens (roughly) between 1001px and 1136px wide: resizing the window makes the search button from the search results overlays the right nav.

On Meta...
[image: bug on Meta]

Stack Overflow...
[image: bug on Stack Overflow]

And SFF, and others with the new theme:
[image: bug on SFF]

I don't know if it's relevant but apparently it also happens on job searches, per [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372348) on MSO, but that was another browser and not the exact same button - never used job search on SO, don't know how it behaves.

Comment: Confirmed. Firefox Android 63.0b7.

Comment: I'm not seeing it in Chrome but was able to repro in FF 62 and 63. Thanks. We'll look at it.

Comment: This should be fixed now

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this bug has been reported or not (honestly I've looked at only half of the response post here): the badge notification graphics clash with the frame beneath it as shown in my screen grab, across all browser zooms (shown below are 110%, 50%, 200%).

My system is MacBook Pro laptop with a 2880x1880 screen by default mimicking 1440x900, running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6, and the browser is Google Chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Yep! We're working on it. We have several reports on it and are trying to get a fix out soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility)

### Process Objection

I think this issue underlies a lot of the other ones we're seeing. Several of the issues raised on my "home" stack (RPG.SE) with regards to poor contrast, items distinguished by color only, etc., garnered the response "that's a valid concern and we'll look at that when we start thinking about accesssibility issues, after the new layout is completely rolled out." While I appreciate that it is on the agenda in the first place, **the appropriate time to be thinking about accessibility is day 1, before planning, let alone making, any changes.**

Answer (score 2):

Is the minimal width of the page on `chat.stackexchange.com` and `chat.stackoverflow.com` gonna be considered in the redesign?

---

Here's a userscript that resolves this issue: [Fix chat.SE and chat.SO main page minimum width](https://stackapps.com/questions/7922/fix-chat-se-and-chat-so-main-page-minimum-width)

Comment: They will be as it is. No change  For background of this post, read [Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/357396) and [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/357396).

Comment: @NogShine no matter, I have considered it myself :p

Answer (score 2):

The preference to hide the left sidebar really wasn't as useful as I initially thought. The main issue is that it hides some actions I used very often behind two clicks, instead of only the one click needed previously. By far the most common page I want to navigate to is the "Questions" page, to view the newest questions on the site. On SO another common action is to switch to my Team instead of the main site.

My initial expectation was that this preference would simply move those items back to the kind of horizontal menu we have on classic SE sites. But instead it hides everything behind a hamburger menu.

There's plenty of space in the header for MSE, and on SO there's even less vertical space occupied as there is only the top bar, and no header below it. I think switching the sidebar to a horizontal menu if the "hide left navigation" is checked would be a large improvement over the unconditional hamburger menu. This trades width against height, and not width against an additional click every time.

Comment: Isn't this basically just...activating the old design instead? Not saying that'd be a bad idea. ;-) But it's unlikely that is really an otpion.

Comment: @ChristianRau it would be very similar to the old design, yes. I also wouldn't have expected this to be likely to happen, but then SE actually added a preference to hide the left navigation bar, so they seem to want to cater to the users that dislike that sidebar very strongly.

Comment: Yeah but a horizontal bar isn't going to scale well for users with 2 dozen teams!

Comment: @KevinB you can always put the overflow into a hamburger menu on that horizontal bar, that's a very common pattern for responsive designs.

Comment: i mean... those users are paying customers.

Comment: @Kevin The convenience of a few shouldn't cause inconvenience to many. Besides, it is always possible to scroll horizontally. Also, "Teams" can be hosted separate from StackOverflow, just like all the other SE sites are presently, and this left bar gimmick can be implemented only on that site.  It makes sense to have a dedicated site for paying customers, coupling "Teams" with StackOverflow just makes things complicated. Besides, we are just assuming that paying customers get preferential treatment. I know that's what commonly happens, but it hasn't been explicitly stated.

Comment: nothing adblock or a users script can’t fix @Thanos

Comment: @KevinB So install userscripts on multiple browsers and devices is a solution? Or are you saying access the site only from a single browser on a single device?

Comment: single device. why in the world would you use multiple browsers devices at the same time for SO? it’s not like you’re QA testing SO. you only have to set up a user script once per device you choose. it’s easy.

Comment: @kevin, I'm accessing SE from 5 different devices, not all of them support user scripts. And you also have to keep user scripts updated, and they tend to break occasionally, ...  . User scripts are at best a workaround, they're never a solution

Comment: i mean... i can’t help that you make your life so hard for yourself. ‍♂️

Comment: This was raised by other users as well. E.g., see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370249/2422776) on MSO

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion for improving the usefulness of the left-hand nav bar. There are complaints about there being too many "hamburger-like" menu buttons. I suggest to remove the community one, and put it in the left-hand navigation bar.

This is what SO looks like for me today:

[image]

It would be easy to add links to other pages in the SE network under the "Public" heading (sorry for the very awful mock-up, UIs is not what I do):

[image]

There could be an additional button there to customize which links are shown (for those folks who make accounts on all SE sites, you know who you are).

**EDIT:** My thoughts mirror the ones expressed in [this answer to the "Ch-ch-changes" post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307869/376604).

Comment: Please, please, please no. The content in the left bar is *local* content. Specific to that site. I really, really do not want the site selector here.

Comment: We seriously considered that approach in the early days of the design explorations. I still think it has merit. But we decided to not implement it at this time. It may come back, you never know.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is a stylish script to fix a lot of the problems:
https://userstyles.org/styles/161460/se-left-nav-scroll-with-page
Screenshot:
[image]

Improved:

- Sticky to top
- Grey background
- Simpler hierarchy

A lot of the code was copied from [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1724993).

Comment: The style is nice, but it is active for all sites, not just Stack Overflow/Exchange. To fix it, you can wrap the whole style in `@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("stackexchange.com"),
domain("serverfault.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("stackapps.com"),
domain("mathoverflow.net"), domain("askubuntu.com")
{ ... }` - copied from [here](https://userstyles.org/styles/136521/stackexchange-sticky-header).

Comment: @Kobi : Done ***.***

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Left nav appears to misbehave on the Stack Overflow [/jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page in Edge (41.16299.15.0) browser**

The side navbar seems to float into the job search results area when the window width exceeds approximately 1274px. See screenshots below -

Width at 1920px -

[image]

[image]

[image]

In Firefox it looks fine -

[image]

(Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate - I did search but couldn't find anything)

Comment: That's hella weird. I can repro in 41.x, but not 42.x. And the repro is only for logged in users... Edge still considered the links to be in the sidebar (that's where they're clickable), but the text is rendered mid-page for some reason. Weird.

Comment: With help from balpha, got a fix pending. It should go out on Monday. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Brilliant, and no worries!

Comment: The fix is out in prod. Let me know if you're still seeing any issues.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Hopefully this has not been posted yet, but the website is really *going to great lengths* to want me to accept an answer.  The following image demonstrates it all.

---

In case I did not make my feedback clear enough, the text circled in the image displaced the vote/answer/view counters from where they should have been shown.

[image]

Comment: Hey Frenzy, I flagged this as not an answer since it seems to be completely unrelated to the topic of this post. If you feel strongly about this, then I'd suggest you post it as a feature request on its own.

Comment: @JoeFriend It looks like a bug to me, since the message should probably be above the title, instead of squeezing it "to great lengths" (or should we say "widths"?).

Comment: @JoeFriend This is a valid bug that seems to only occur on sites where the responsive design has rolled out. The italicized text seems more like exaggerated sarcasm rather than an opinionated rant. As such, I dismissed your flag.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog Not debating whether it is a bug or not. It's just not relevant to this post. The profiles page is NOT responsive so that can't be the cause here as best as I can figure.

Comment: Well, then maybe it would be better to post this as a separate question (cc @JoeFriend)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

From the left navigation, if I select **Unanswered** option I can see the Questions and Unanswered options are selected.

I hope it should be highlight the Unanswered option only. It causes confusion which tab we are in now.

**When hide the left navigation:**

> [image: Questions and Unanswered]

**With the left navigation:**

> [image: Questions and Unanswered]

Comment: Unanswered also questions right? I think it they selected it by that basis. But yes, that will be confusing which tab you are on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the left-bar should be collapsed by default as most logged in or anonymous user will see the same thing there. Also currently IMO it distracts the main question view. Or at the very least- as you resize the window down, the sidebar should be the first one to collapse. Currently the right hand panel moves to the bottom which is the second most important piece in this page (after the question).

I'm only talking about the question page. Other pages look brilliant with the sidebar. It's just in the question page where this new sidebar hurts my eye.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **+1** from me! The sidebar on the left is great. It makes the main column more centered and thus it is significantly better for comfortable reading (on a wide screen). Seriously - a bigger left margin is a remedy to the former layout.

Though I have a pair of minor suggestions.
.

#### Right sidebar & resizing the window ("responsive design")

Currently the right sidebar moves towards center when shrinking the window and then at some point - woop!  it just dissapears. I see, this is kind of "responsive design". But is it possible to make it the other way: say if I shrink the window width, it would be better if the right sidebar at some moment starts to just 'clip' under the border. I mean it will just be clipping by the window border more and more when shrinking the window. And then, when it is away, the main column starts to
shrink 'adaptively'.

Maybe it is hard to implement, but I beleive the users who need smaller views will much appreciate that.
And there will be less rearrangement happening on the screen when resizing the window.

Also, the gap between the main column and the right sidebar is still too small. Please add ~ 15 pixels more spacing.
.

#### Maybe add something useful to the new sidebar?

Consider adding e.g. "My profile" and "Other SE sites" to the left sidebar - anyway there is a lot of space.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Answer (score 1):

## I can't review edits in mobile properly

When I click an **edit (1)** link I get this popup centered in my screen. I cannot pan left to see what was removed or access any controls on the left side to change the view. I can pan right to see the full review and buttons, but that's not enough to be able to conduct a proper edit review.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Responsive is a work in progress. We haven't tackled these views yet. You would need to switch back to the mobile view for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools)

After I create a community event, I see this jumble of text:

[image: Worldbuilding screenshot]

The event view, which used to be multi-line, is now pushed into a table.  That table must still fit within the (responsive) width of the pane.  URLs are inherently long, and some event names are too.  And the timing text is verbose.  Result: lots of unfortunate line wrap (while there's extra room below), and the links are smooshed into the last column where they're harder to see.

For comparison, here is what this page looks like on a site with the old design:<sup>1</sup>

[image: Workplace screenshot]

Here the table is replaced with rows of text.  The event name is on a line by itself.  The next line contains the URL.  Below that are the date information and who created it.  Below that are the links.  The display actually takes a little *less* vertical space than the tabular view, in addition to being much easier to read.

Could we have the line-based layout instead of the table layout on this page?

This bug was also [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316256/162102) on the post about beta/unthemed sites, but it exists on other sites with the new design so I'm raising it here too.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Workplace is the last site where (a) the new design hasn't been done yet and (b) I have a diamond so I could do this test.

Answer (score 0):

"Hide left navigation" does not actually hide the left navigation. Either hide it or rename the setting.

Comment: Yes, it does. You have to disable for every site for now.

Comment: Ah ok, the post linked on home was on Meta and following that took me to the wrong preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The search bar does not align with page contents and this is driving my design OCD crazy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## I can't upload images on mobile

I get the option to hit the image upload button, but when I hit that button and choose my image, here's what I see next:

> [image]

I cannot pan left or right or zoom out. The upload button is off screen. I can't reach it to upload my image.

Instead I have to switch on viewing this site in desktop mode in my mobile browser, and do my image upload that way:

> [image]

Comment: We are actively working on making this experience responsive. Coming soon. ;)

Answer (score -3):

Just bite the bullet and build a platform level capability to support user templating similar to [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_%28JavaScript_library%29). I don’t mean be like React specifically, or that complex really; I mean any kind of template syntax that makes it relatively easy layout the page and components and very simple theming with a high level syntax.

This would be a ridiculous and unnecessarily flexible feature for most sites, but this is a a developer site. People would love it and use it.

They wouldn’t even have to know the syntax, because they could just browse and copy an existing well designed and refined template from the ecosystem that would instantly appear without even any official support.

Comment: "This is a developer site". - Except this network is made up of 170+ sites with many users who are not developers.

Comment: @Catija So? First look at the activity. The % of users with technical knowledge sufficient to do this goes way beyond SO, and even with SO alone it's by far the largest community.  Secondly, investing in something to serve so much of your user base well does not diminish growing other non-technical communities (although I bet you'd find people using in most stacks).   You can argue it all you want, but I'd bet a little money if it was carefully explained to all stacks, including the downside, which is mostly opportunity cost of other potential enhancements, that it would get voted in.

Comment: "Voted in"? This isn't a democracy. It's a business. We don't really get a vote. The staff decides.

Comment: @Catija respectfully, weak refutation. It’s not the point I’m making. The point is, an important part of most business is when doing product/service design, focussing on whats most appealing to a broad set of users is crucial.  Sure, you can say I may be guessing wrong about how to segment and prioritize user demand, but I not referring to government here or proposing a bill of rights. Thought experiments about what many users might want, or theoretically vote on, or whatever, are obsessed on throughout the business world.  The business model is intertwined with all of this of course.

Comment: Sorry to rant but I think it’s important to note none of this is based on developer elitism. That would be the complete opposite of my philosophy. People always say when using apps, oh I messed up, I’m not very good with technology. I tell them messing up is an impossibility. It’s the developers/designers job to make it easy enough to make you successful at whatever scenario. We messed up, not them when this happens. Serious, just like some people think the customer is always right I’m obsessed with the idea that a user can’t screw up, we just have to iterate and do better and better.

Comment: Giving important sections of the page classes/id's that you can easily target would likely be good enough for most users who want to alter the look/feel of the site. We're even already most of the way there.

Answer (score -4):

In the left window the navigation thing is on. See how much unused space it steals from the main content of the site? I wanted to reclaim it fully by disabling the left side column. Instead even more space got stolen by the right side column which was hidden before but then appeared (in the right window).

Some (in the comments to this post) argue that the right sidebar needs its own space and it's fair how it steals that much space for itself. That's not what I wanted in this example, but I agree that sometimes that's what you'd want.

I think we can meet halfway by creating a vertical bar or a toggle button which collapses the right side widget when you want the questions to take up all the window space.

[image]

Comment: That was true of the old design too -- any space left on the page after the end of the HNQ list is empty.

Comment: On reddit, the posts and comments start using that space when the sidebar ends. So that's definitely possible to fix.

Comment: If you're saying that it's a conscious choice, then it was bad before and is bad now, in my opinion.

Comment: i mean, well, yeah, anything is "possible", doesn't make it the right design option though.

Comment: It's not always a good thing to use all available space. It can look muddy and reading wide chunks of text can be quite difficult for some people. It's (generally) much easier for our eyes to read narrower columns than wider ones.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the page becomes even narrower when the idea behind disabling the left nav was to increase available space for the main site's content. I can't be the only person on the site who uses half-monitor windows to look at 2 windows at the same time. I'll post the scripts to fix this nonsense if I need to, but I think it really should be the official option.

Comment: It's all about available space. If there's enough space for the right menu, it will display. If there isn't, it will be placed below the answers (until they incorporate it more into the main column for that browser size in a later update.) There's nothing crazy going on here; by disabling the left menu there's now enough space to show the right one. Why wouldn't it show?

Comment: As a fix if you just don't want the right bar, you could just set that div to display none, then set the width of the mainbar to 100%.