# "Hot Posts" Removal with New Nav?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, new-nav, navigation, sidebar

In the comments to one of the [answers under the new nav question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310916/300377), theres a comment about removing the "Hot Posts" from the sidebar, show below.

[image]

This comment was the first I've heard of it, and I've been following the new nav closely. Monica does provide a solution in the third comment, but I'm concerned about the lack of communication on whats going & whats staying in the bar.

Could someone from the PM/Dev team chime in, and describe what is getting removed, and if any improvements or replacements are being added?

---

Personally, I'd like to see these lists expanded, and the ability to blacklist or whitelist sites from the "Hot Posts" added. I find a lot of new, niche stacks through this sidebar, and its greatly increased my use of the platform, allowing me access to communities I wouldn't think to look for on my own.

Theres a lot of stacks on the platform, and I don't have the time to be a member on every single one of the sites I'm interested in. This component lets me still access their content, without the participation requirements. Instead, I can put more time into the stacks I use for work.

I know not everyone likes the bar, or uses it, but if they could blacklist sites they don't want to see, and just have the bar provide content from sites they are interested in, or just remove it entirely (like I have on salesforce.stack using an adblocker), I think the problem would solve itself.

I read somewhere about the sidebar possibly having "Custom Searches", and I'm hoping they support cross-site searches, at the very least.

Comment: Huh? That comment is only about very narrow page width views, not all views.

Comment: Yeah, you're only reading a few comments out of an entire context there. As part of the new responsive design, the Hot Network Questions section gets hidden when the page gets collapsed to a single column. We're not removing the feature entirely.

Comment: Ah, my first meta post ... Ill never forget this shame.. Ill post that snippet as an answer & self accept to get it off the open question list. Thanks for being kind with my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yeah, you're only reading a few comments out of an entire context there. As part of the new responsive design, the Hot Network Questions section gets hidden when the page gets collapsed to a single column. We're not removing the feature entirely.

Credit: animuson♦

Whoops!