# Reputation number color changed recently; was this intended?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, design, top-bar

I just happened to notice that the color of the reputation numbers is different than before.

Last time I checked the color was white (from an old screenshot I took):

[image]

But now it seems that it is grey-ish:

[image]

**What was the reason for this change in color?** IMHO I liked the white color better, as it was easier to read. I also wonder if this could have something to do with the recent Maintenance the site went through.

*Edit:* Extracting the colors, I get that before it was indeed white (255,255,255), but now it is some sort of gray (187,192,196)

Comment: Why the DVs? This appears to have happened in all the sites (with black topbar BG), so it should be relevant... was this a change that was announced before?

Comment: there is an announcement in the sidebar related to theming: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?cb=1

Comment: @rene yup, I checked it before, but it doesn't mention about this thing (only that on other sites changes will start to appear on Late June). I guess adding a post there about this color could be another option

Comment: @rene technically, this isn't about the theming, though... it's about the top bar.

Comment: I'm not seeing that greyish background you have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af8cj.png but my numbers color seem to match yours (although I'm not a design/visual person so I might be wrong on this)

Comment: @Catija well, that is true but IIRC also badges were going to be uniform so I assume all styling, including the topbar styling is impacted by this, no?

Comment: @rene other users I commented have noticed also. The pics I provided show the difference more clearly. If you see the one you provided the 101 is in grey-ish, when before it should have been white (going to take a measure of the colors on my screenshots)

Comment: @rene but the rollout of the SO top bar to all sites doesn't seem to be part of the responsive design rollout... seeing as one is on all sites and the other isn't. I don't think the content of the top bar (which icons appear there) are quite the same...

Comment: @DarkCygnus This is most likely due to a theming change. I don't believe it is intentional but will check with the designer (who is out for a couple days).

Comment: thanks @JoeFriend will keep engaged if any follow-ups come

Comment: What is "n, which is blocked"?

Comment: @user298438 oooooh I see haha, it's an old screenshot I took, and that red part was a connection error I was getting, which motivated me to take the screenshot. It's there because it was the only screenshot I could find that illustrated the change in color :)

Comment: Relate/Derivated post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311574/332286

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now fixed. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think they still haven't propagated to other sites... I will be checking and accept this answer when the changes propagate :)

Comment: I see the change on MSE only, but the original change *to* gray occurred everywhere.  Is this a propagation delay, or was it accidentally fixed only here?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've pinged the designer who made the change and we will get it fixed.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Should be fixed everywhere.

Comment: @JoeFriend yup it is, now I can see the [change in color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311569/332286). Thanks, accepting this answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this change had an undesired effect in international SO sites (which have a light gray top bar). Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311574.

Comment: @bfavaretto hmm it seems like it did, as if white was applied regardless of background.

Comment: @bfavaretto that other post is also now completed

Comment: In fact it is, thanks for letting me know @DarkCygnus

Answer (score 5):

New:

[image]

Old:

[image]

Seems that the changes have now propagated to other sites, and the reputation color is back to White again.

Comment: Yeah, it is white again.