# New reputation color makes it very hard to read on international Stack Overflow sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

There has been a change to the reputation color of the top-bar, I think this is part of the new themes of the Stack Exchange network.

But it makes it very hard to read on all sites, I've created an account on [ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), and had one on [es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) and can confirm it's happening on all sites.

Here is an image from [ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

[image: white]

The 300+ rep is because I joined those sites.

And here is one from [es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

[image: another white]

Here is an image of the classes that affect the reputation, as we can see they are `.top-bar .my-profile .-rep`

[image: inspected element]

Comment: Likely related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311172/reputation-number-color-changed-recently-was-this-intended

Comment: @SOLO it looks like, apparently that change is what causes this bug

Comment: I left a comment to the product manager who answered the other question. Now we can be sure the staff will be notified of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the issue is gone. I created accounts on ru and ja, and the rep seems ok (black, and readable):

On [ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/):

[image]

On [ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/):

[image]

Comment: Yes!! that's why they put a [ status-completed ] tag. I'll accept your answer, thanks :)

Comment: @KacosPro no problem, sometimes changes take time to propagate even if the status-completed tag is added, but now we can see they took place correctly :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't now that, in that case thanks again for the answer!