# Checkbox doesn't disable left nav

Tags: feature-request, left-nav

In my Preferences, I have checked

> Hide left navigation
>   When you check this box, the left navigation will no longer be pinned to the left of the page.

but the left nav bar is still there on all of my SE pages (all the ones I've checked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> update: [Hide Left nav everywhere with a global preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311528/hide-left-nav-everywhere-with-a-global-preference)

The left navigation preference is per site. So, if you set it on Stack Overflow, then you need to also set it on Meta Stack Exchange. There are requests to make this a global preference that you can set once and it applies for all sites. That is under consideration.

Comment: Why would you *not* make it a global preference? Surely, you realize that setting it on a couple dozen sites separately would be extremely annoying?

Comment: @jpmc26 We certainly are aware of this. There are no global preferences currently. Adding support for them is possible, but non-trivial. As stated, we are considering adding this.

Comment: As I recall, "Disable top bar stickiness" did not have to be set on every site separately.

Comment: @jpmc26 Your memory fails you. ;) Well, kinda. It is not sticky on the network sites and there is no option to make it so.

Comment: @Joe well, all Email Settings are global, and changing them on one site affects all other sites.

Comment: One of the biggest benefits from my end of making this built into the layout rather than a setting (other than the simplicity of finding it) is that I may want it active on my small screen laptop, I'd probably hide the sidebar but on my work monitors leave it open. It's much easier to click a open/close toggle than go to the settings page on each site. I'm also assuming that this isn't cookie based, so if I want a different experience on different machines/devices, I'd have to reset it every time I switch (twice a day) for every site I use, including metas, so about 10-12 sites. That's a lot.

Comment: Note that several clicks are required to turn off the nav bar--the setting is kind of buried.  I'm going to disable it incrementally as I use sites, which means that for sites I  visit rarely, I will have to figure out where the checkbox is buried over and over again.

Comment: A simple solution is to just adblock it away.

Comment: Or you could follow the KISS principle and disable it by default. People who want to see the left navigation bar can enable it on the sites they need. It is a good design principle to make the most common usecase simple, and introduce the friction (if unavoidable) in the less common usecases.