# Re-enabling left navigation doesn't work

Tags: bug, left-nav

When the new sidebar appeared, I've quickly hidden it.

However, I wanted to replicate a bug report on Meta Stack Overflow, so wanted to re-enable it.

My steps:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This bug occurs on MSO and SO. It does not occur on MSE, however, there the settings just work.

Environment: FF 60.0.1 x64, Windows 7

Comment: No repro with Chrome. After you refresh, still an hamburger?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It doesn't occur on MSE, though, there the settings just work. If I refresh on the settings page, the box stays unticked, but I don't have the nav bar anymore. It only appears on the settings page when I've just unticked the option, navigating anywhere makes it disappear again.

Comment: possibly a side effect of recent change to make it a [global preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311528/165773)