# How can I remove or hide the left navigation bar?

Tags: support, navigation, left-nav

Can I remove the navigation bar as this is distracting and clutters the site especially on Stack Overflow.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks to this "feature" I have to scroll horizontally to see the complete content of the page on my screen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go to [your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current).
2. Click [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).
3. Click "Preferences" under "Site Settings".
4. Tick the "Hide left navigation" checkbox:

   > [image]
5. Profit. (No need to click any save button, action is immediate)

Note that this is a per-site setting, you'll have to repeat this on every site in Stack Exchange you join.

Also, hiding the left nav does **not** restore the previous tabbed design. Instead, it will collapse all the links into hamburger menu on the top left, as if you're always on mobile:

> [image: collapsed menu]

Which becomes:

> [image: menu opened]

Comment: consider [edit]ing to add an explanation on how to get to navigation items when it is disabled (I for one like the way how [it was explained at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369107/839601))

Comment: Should i go hide it on all sites manually?

Comment: @TinusJackson yes, when it will be rolled to all sites later this month. For now it's only here on MSE. (in addition to SO.)

Comment: @gnat actually this might fit a separate answer, as the question itself is only how to hide the nav bar.

Comment: I proposed this because knowing this seems to be very important for readers, up to the point of making "straight" answer unusable. For example the first time I learned about disabling at MSO I had to enable it back because I couldn't get to these items. I only succeeded to disable it after learning how to get to the items from the referred MSO answer

Comment: @gnat fair point. Will pull something off later, have to go now.

Comment: @gnat sorry for the delay, edited now.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I would never have figured out how to remove this noise on my own.

Comment: At the basic level, the design itself should be reconsidered. It is entirely wasteful and forced content to be even more narrow. A beauty idea: one very easy-to-access button to enable entire width view for content.

Comment: @drew. you better start a new feature request, as a comment here is gets 0 exposure and 0 chance to be done.