# Don't put the searched tags on top of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, user-interface

I don't like the new layout. This is how Stack Overflow welcomed me today with my usual tag-search list which I have been using for the past many years (saved in a bookmark). I don't want to see this at the top:

[image]

**Suggestion**: maybe you could implement a feature to store searches and give them a name.

Comment: I did not bother to read beyond the "It's just ugly", just downvoted. If you want to be treated seriously, talk nicely. Lots of good people spent lots of time on the new design, they do not deserve such rudeness.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: you're right, removed it. But i just wanted to express how it looks to me and i'm referring only to the summary of my searched tags at the top which seems to be redundant. I thought meta questions with discussion tags can contain own opinions and a huge, unnecessary list at the top looks ugly, imho.

Comment: Well, saying "this is ugly" makes it personal. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Duplicate from here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311173/245360.

Comment: re the suggestion: it already exists. Start [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters). You can create a filter, name it, and have it return questions matching a set of tags on a single site.

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't live @Sha. I want the previous tabbed interface back on SO.

Comment: @PatrickHofman umm... what? Looks like you replied to wrong comment?

Comment: No, it was on your "re: suggestion". That suggestion isn't really a working solution. The old "new nav" on SO was much, much better. @Sha

Comment: @PatrickHofman so what you mean by "that isn't live"? What isn't live?

Comment: The live updating of the tag filter results @Sha

Comment: @PatrickHofman but they are, up to one minute which is really minor. Just checked now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNbkP.png

Comment: But you have to manually refresh the page. That is what I meant @Sha

Comment: @PatrickHofman oh, I see now. Well, that might be worth a separate feature request, no? :)

Comment: I think filters are too expensive, since they are network-wide too. I wouldn't use them if the question page will do.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: thanks for the suggestion with the exchange filters. I didn't know them. Nice, maybe i will use them. But not quite the same if you only want to use stackoverflow.

Comment: @PatrickHofman of course, it's an overkill, but will do in case the standard methods won't work.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: well, i'm using this quite often per day, it's my standard action on stackoverflow to reload my tags. So if this is overkill it might not be appropriate.

Comment: Well, you can also use userscript to make it look better if you're into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed.

The design didn't really consider pages with multiple tags.  It was really intended for things like:

> ## Public Questions tagged [asp.net]

You can really tell because your header has `[asp.net or vb.net or ...]` instead of the correct format, `[asp.net] or [vb.net] or ...`.

I've restructured the header for the tags page so if two or more tags are present, the header will more closely resemble the search results header with a short fixed heading followed by a normal sized blurb listing all the tags:

[image: Screenshot of the new header]

Ironically, this isn't that much shorter than the previous header, but it's a lot prettier, more useful, and consistent with the search results page.

Comment: Great job, that looks perfect imo. While you say _this isn't that much shorter_, it makes a substantial difference on my (small) second screen.

Comment: While this is better, it's still too much screen space. Note that we only need these horrible URLs because the new nav was deprecated.