# Responsive design on a phone indents posts and comments too much

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, responsive-design

This is what a question on MSE looks like on my phone, with left nav turned *off*:

[image: screenshot showing lots of indent/whitespace]

For comparison, here is what a question from a site that doesn't yet have the responsive design looks like:

[image: screenshot showing better use of space]

Long comments are especially annoying with the new design; short lines mean more stuff gets pushed out of view.  Even questions are kind of frustrating to read with all that extra indentation; the current mobile view puts the voting buttons next to the title, *above* the body, so that the question can have the whole width.  Further, I bet that when the indented post links are joined by "mod" and "start bounty" like in the second screenshot, that line's gonna wrap.

In a small viewport like a phone, *please* use the page width better.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310941/284336

Comment: @Catija thanks, edited.  (That it's planned for the future doesn't help when the current mobile theme is no longer available; if they don't address this then mobile is going to get worse before it eventually (we hope) gets back to where it is now.  That's...suboptimal.)

Comment: The old mobile theme is still available for MSE. Scroll all the way down and tap "Mobile" in the footer.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog thanks; I didn't see that.  (There's a lot of stuff to scroll past, including the HNQ list, and I missed it.)

Comment: I've filed a bug and we will look at possible solutions for this.