# Too much horizontal space on mobile

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, mobile-web, responsive-design

> [image: Too much horizontal space]

On a mobile device, the responsive design mostly fits a single page, but the "Post as guest" pushes out and increases the horizontal space for the whole page.

In the image above, the red line is where the scroll *should* end, and the blue area is extra dead space.

OS: Android,
Browser: Firefox

Comment: Possibly related: [Responsive design on a phone indents posts and comments too much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312356/21960)

Comment: Can you include your OS and browser version in your report. On Android Oreo, with Firefox and Chrome, StackExchange looks great in desktop mode (except for upper right, Avatar Rep missing due to CSS vs. DPI - Bug, filed) and acceptable in mobile mode.