# Unable to upload an image or even close upload popup when responsive design is on

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, uploader, responsive-design

When responsiveness is enabled on the site, I can’t upload or even close the image upload dialog due to unscallable nature of the upload popup. Here’s the screenshot:

> [image: upload]

“Add image” and “close” buttons are not visible.

Comment: Looks like you're using Android. What browser?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog current screenshot is from iPad (Chrome) in split mode, but first time I saw the issue on Android (Chrome too) in portrait mode.

Comment: Does disabling responsiveness in the footer fix the issue?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog when responsiveness is off I can zoom and shift the page to access mentioned buttons.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I think you can achieve same behavior on any desktop browser when window width is small enough.

Comment: @älёxölüt is there still a bug? There was a change in the uploader design.

Answer (score 2):

While the [quote below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness/) is still generally true, the new insert link and insert image experience we recently rolled out is a big improvement when using the new themes on mobile.

> This is a work in progress and this step is a part of our effort to validate our significant changes to page layout code. Not all pages are responsive yet, asking a question and many moderator or review activities will not work in a smaller viewport and you'll need to expand the window. We are making improvements to this experience week by week, so it will just keep getting better.
>
> We haven't fully optimized this for mobile devices, but click the "full site" option in the footer and you will get the responsive design on your phone. If for some reason you need access to the non-responsive version, we have a temporary feature for turning that on. Just click "Disable Responsive" option in the footer. This is a temporary feature that will go away once all the pages/features have been made responsive. The mobile optimized view will also remain in place until we finish making all the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joe. But I’m not clearly understand should I report such bugs in the future or not? I mean when the responsiveness is not officially fully supported yet.

Comment: @alexolut Feel free to report bugs and I'll do my best to collect them for the time when we can focus on mobile. It will (hopefully) be later this year after we roll out themes to all sites.

Comment: BTW do you know when resposiveness will come to localized SOs (in particular to SO in Russian)?

Comment: @alexolut In the next week or so we will roll out the new theme & responsiveness on at least one localized site (to flush out bugs) and shortly thereafter on all of them.

Comment: @JoeFriend so, how is all going on? (:

Comment: @Suvitruf there was a change in the last few days, is this still an issue?

Comment: @ShadowWizard this issue is not relevant anymore. But here is [another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMsSY.png).