# Can I keep the old design? It looks better than the new one

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

The new responsive design with a left nav-bar has been rolled out on various sites, and users have complained about it being ugly and counterproductive.

The first example I would like to present is the 200+ **net negative** score of the official announcement, [Live: Left nav, new theming and responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/350567), as well as some answers under that question.

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310940
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310945
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310973
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311254
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311179

And some other posts and comments

- [Left nav bar thingy has too much whitespace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369338)
- [What does our long term community need? What does our long term community need to feel valued?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t#comment624473_373160)

While I understand that this complete re-design is a big project and it's subject to bugs and features in its early times, it doesn't deny the fact that many people don't like it, even after those bugs fixed.

#### The feature request part of this question:

Give users an option to stay with the old design. I don't care if the new design is the default for new users, but I DO care if I have to adapt this ugly new one. I also won't care if all future bugs and feature-requests to the old design are denied. It looks very well as-is (i.e. in its current state). I just like it, plainly, simply.

Answer (score 13):

While I'm not thrilled about this change either, I accept their decision and I'm well aware that allowing people to revert to the old design means **tons** of development work, possibly hundreds of dev hours, which I prefer be spent on more important things, be it fixing bugs or adding new features.

Even Google, with thousands upon thousands of developers and unlimited resources don't offer the option to revert to old design when they change it.

So my opinion on this: try to get used to the changes. If you really can't, look for userscripts that can change it to something else which is easier to accept.

Comment: last paragraph edited.

Comment: I also accept their decision, but in **my** (and many other users') opinion it's ugly, undeniably.

Comment: Edit is not really relevant, the new design is deeper than just fonts and colors. They changed the whole logic (how they create the design) behind the scenes, how they load things, etc. It can't just be reverted.

Comment: but the old design is still available and remain on some sites, no?

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ Yes, but only until all sites have been converted to unified theming, at which point we can finally remove a *lot* of hard-to-maintain legacy code.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ Temporarily, soon it will be removed. And then they can make changes much easier, without being afraid to break something on one site and without having to test some tiny change on 150+ sites. (Or roll a small change just to see it broke something on one site)

Comment: @balpha just curious, what's your role in the unified theming project?

Comment: @balpha If I want a part of the old design, should I open it as a feature request? That would *partially* solve the problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Much of the infrastructure stuff (i.e. implementation, as opposed to creating actual designs).

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ You can, but I wouldn't get my hopes up too high. You're approaching things based on *visual* changes that you see, but "give me an option to make X continue to look like Y" is probably a bigger undertaking than "just don't delete this particular CSS file".

Comment: Well,  **even Google does design studies** before changing stuff and they know how UX is influenced by UI design. Yet, in my own humble opinion as someone with a BA in visual communications, I have to say SE dropped the ball hard. It's not only the left sidebar and visual centering glitch, it's also the right sidebar hopelessly floating centered under the main content on sone screens… so much for "featured Qs" et al even being noticed. ([details](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1104/12164)) TL:DR: this design looks and feels like an amateur job.

Comment: Try browsing Google.com with a user agent code that emulates Internet Explorer 8 or Internet Explorer 6. Older UIs are served to these users.