# Do all Stack Exchange sites use the same template?

Tags: discussion, design, architecture

Do all Stack Exchange sites use the same template?

I mean, the Stack Overflow company can create many similar sites, such as:

- https://superuser.com
- https://askubuntu.com
- https://patents.stackexchange.com
- https://area51.stackexchange.com

and so on, I am guessing, if all the sites use a same template (just with a different CSS), they can update conveniently, such as fix a bug, all the sites use one template, they all can be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, almost* all use the same template. In the [footer](/#footer), at the bottom right, you can find the version number:

> rev 2018.10.16.31919

As for the design (CSS), they're in the [process of uniformizing that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes), but so far that has been received with [mixed results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/295232).

<sup>*: [Area 51](https://area.stackexchange.com) is the only exception, besides of source the non-Q&A sites like [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) and the [API site](https://api.stackexchange.com)</sup>