# Size of the search textbox in the top bar is increased suddenly on all the sites

Tags: support, bug, design, search, top-bar

Size of the search textbox in the top bar is increased suddenly. I can recall the size of the textbox being smaller previously.

Is the textbox size increased on purpose, or is this a bug?

> [image]

Comment: Also, favorite button (star) became much smaller and vote arrows bit larger. This all points toward overall design changes, yes.

Comment: Previous UI isn't relevant as it's from se.com, which has different design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't have reference for old UI, so took screenshot from SE. Now rollback my edit.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310911/369802)... it seems it was big, got smaller and is now big again :)