# Email links don't open the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

**EDIT: I was offline for the last few hours, so I couldn't look at the other question of which this one here *was* a duplicate.**

It is not a duplicate, because the linked question mentions Stack Exchange links explicitly. The problem I face has to do with the fact, that links in Stack Exchange mailings are not exactly what the Stack Exchange app would expect an Stack Exchange link to look like. I would not even call this a Stack Exchange link, since it doesn't lead to a site within the Stack Exchange network you would normally link to.

I guess they are some sort of click-tracker link, or something like that, but that's not the important part, here. Here's what one of the links looks like:

```
http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?upn=pDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnZrGP7ewVN5UzFsPjLNsxf37lv5vH-2FL7YDbAQsAtLugYNp-2BJiZcu65iHCdCmWwcPykni0h3G-2BW3a5DJQvmvpqO5YYk0exrZkOZd357pJfsQtX23gZixSuNBvjUBdJW0S-2FYJxGOjASUTK1FgJWcFKhWk-3D_AOPg-2F-2BQL2BN1Z1adM2aHoJZemfJJPhUU1r33PmBub3XkdttNEsj9eAI3iXegmVDgNR1kPnNqBKQmCk2dsyn9uQ5g2T8fxWFcEgLgWVEljU9HeN8V3E9CiWFKeHBN3AsBll3Ol5ooWPcw1zAzDtJBxhi9y23WRvLODAGnxo8GjN2JvPOgbDchbKP4fGLU5bdnPtYYvcBBziE3leh3q-2FXLhm6oVzcczCqFM3tXWWWXJuY-3D
```

*If this question is not attracting any more attention and doesn't loose the dupe tag, I guess I will have waited too long with my edit. In this case, I will delete it and submit a "new" question.*

---

Yeah, so, the title says it. Because the links in the emails are not specifically from Stack Exchange, the app doesn't recognize it as something it's supposed to want to open and each link I tap in an email just opens my mobile browser.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-A520F

  - OS Version: 8.0.0 (A520FXXU8CSC1)

Comment: I didn't realize this was gonna be asked _on_ an SE site. I tapped the bugreport button.

Comment: If the duplicate helps you then you can delete this question. If your question isn't the same then you can comment here or edit your question to clairify the difference. If you think you should have been offered a warning, (or the APP's help was not clear, that you ought to have been warned that submitting a Bug Report posts a question), then you can search for duplicates of that and/or ask a new question. Doing nothing might result in votes and/or closure.

Comment: Alright. It's actually not the same question. I will edit it in about 10 hours. No time now.

Comment: it certainly seems very close. Since the APP is [no longer being developed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/android-app/info) I wouldn't expect your question to remain open for 10 hours, but you can come back and edit it; requesting it be reopened, if it's closed.

Comment: @Rob app development has been frozen for 5 years? What are android users expected to use on a regular basis? The mobile browser? Anyways, I made my edits to differentiate this q from that q. Whatever the benefit of even posting any more bug reports. My expectations are really low, now. Thanks anyway for the link to the announcement.

Comment: Yes, yes. - I use a phone, Firefox, choose "Use Full Site" (bottom of the webpage), then click the FF menu and choose "Request Desktop Site"; then I view an easy to use, almost well laid out (there are some bugs), website that works/looks fairly good. It's also possible to simply use the 'mobile view' but I think most cellphone users do not prefer that. Your expectations for a fix should be low, I didn't want to mislead you into thinking that you should spend a lot of time sticking with the APP. You can upvote the other Q and post convincing reasons here, FWIW. Viewing the full site is *'OK'*.

Comment: @Rob works for me. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: BTW, if you use FF in desktop mode you'll probably want to [disable left navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/282094) to give you a wider view. Clicking **[this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current)** takes you there. A magnifying glass is also handy. 

Comment: Here's the [status of this question's reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/64374). If it gets two more (total three) "Leave Closed" votes, raise a [tag:meta] question or find one of us in chat.

Comment: ...and this finished with a "Leave Closed" outcome. If you're interested in seeing this reopened, ask a new question tagged [tag:meta] [tag:reopen-closed].