# New search on mobile as full site breaks layout

Tags: bug, design, search

One thousand words:
[image: broken :(]

The search hints are obsuring the search box, which isn't particularly helpful.

- My screen has an admittedly small resolution of <s>`360x640`</s> `720x1280`
- I'm using Chrome on Android
- I'm using the 'full site' with 'responsiveness' turned on.

---

**Edit**

It looks like there has been an update, and search now looks like this:

[image: updated design]

Great! You can see what you're typing!

Unfortunately it still looks broken.

Comment: It looks OK on a 1080p Android using Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/xAhf9O3.jpg. 360x640 is an awfully low resolution, even for LG's budget lineup.

Comment: Also, are you sure that's actually the resolution? Your screenshot is 1193x720.

Comment: On your screenshot, the button and link color are wrong, which makes me think that CSS isn't loaded correctly. Can you clear cache and reload the site (or try in incognito) to see if that helps? When I test a 320x640 resolution on my desktop browser, it looks fine. Testing Android/Chrome with a bigger resolution also doesn't show these problems for me.

Comment: @TheWanderer oops, I got it from a browser 'what's my resolution' thing. I've updated to include the resolution of my phone model.

Comment: @HamVocke it's fine, until the keyboard squashes it up. This makes Chrome's effective resolution much smaller.

Comment: @HamVocke - resolution of the viewport in that screenshot is 720x~547

Comment: I'm able to reproduce it by entering split screen and making the window slightly shorter than default: https://i.imgur.com/NGhiiPP.jpg. It seems like the hint layout has some sort of bottom bound, but no hard top bound.

Comment: @HamVocke - I have [a very large screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MSS5.jpg) but if I rotate my phone to landscape mode (which I almost never do) I can easily reproduce this bug. The *hint* must be moved down at least as far as the word "user:1234".

Comment: If I use the phone's back button to dismiss the keyboard the *hint* jumps down into the [perfect position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfCS.jpg) - but even removing the [Ask A Question] button, moving the words "Advanced Search" to the top, and reducing the line spacing [won't be enough to avoid the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZF3y.jpg). Also the [CSS Bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness/310939#comment1016256_310939) that TylerH (Dev) explains remains a problem.

Comment: @Rob wouldn't it be easier to fix the top position?

Comment: @Rob the search bar's bottom position is between "words here" and `answers`. It needs to be lower than that.

Comment: marcellothearcane & @TheWanderer - The question and my [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfCS.jpg) coincide with their positioning, if it's `between "words here" and answers` for The wanderer they need to upload their own screenshot. --- Marcello, Ham probably needs to address the prior CSS Bug first, I haven't suggested "fixing the top position" in the CSS, nor is it clear why one would *need* the "Ask a Question" button on a *search hint* (are you supposed to not make the search, and just ask?).

Comment: @Rob removing the 'ask a question' is probably worth another question (ironically)

Comment: @Rob I already did. My first comment shows the search bar is below the top bar.

Comment: @TheWanderer, so you disagree with [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333042/new-search-on-mobile-as-full-site-breaks-layout?noredirect=1#comment1086606_333042) and not ours.

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce now. The popover component tries to be clever with repositioning when one of its edges hits the viewport. I'm investigating if we can turn this off for this popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed on my phone now.  Since it's not an issue any longer, I'm going to accept this answer.