# Search has become much harder to find on narrow windows

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search, keyboard-shortcuts

Since very recently, search has become a lot harder to reach.

First, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>s</kbd> no longer works. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Second, there used to be a reasonably wide text box at the top of the screen. Now there's only a magnifying glass icon, which you have to click for a text box to appear. Between the "StackExchange" logo on the left and the search icon on the right, there's just some inert space. [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)

[image: screenshot]

The bug only happens at narrow window widths. If I make my window wider than my comfort allows, I do see the normal search box and the keyboard shortcut to activate it works.

Observed both with Chrome and Firefox, logged in or not.

Comment: It seems like that's the mobile interface, where tapping on the search icon to bring up the search box would make sense

Comment: Do you mean “magnifying glass” instead of “hour glass”?

Comment: This is probably browser specific, example: [Firefox Android 68.3b3 in desktop mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0IC1.jpg). SE treats my browser's screen as though it is [740 pixels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness/310939#comment1016299_310939) wide, so my screen is *narrow* too.

Comment: @ColleenV Indeed, on second reading, that's right. Come on, it's only a minute difference. Ok, that was weak. I won't quit my day job.

Comment: Mhh, isn't this a good thing? Then people would start using a real search engine, one that would actually find what they're looking for. The one SE provides is mediocre at best.

Comment: @divibisan I don't understand. Why would you want to have this inert space on a mobile device?

Comment: @Tom What better search engine is there for Stack Exchange content? If it can't search by tag, it is definitely not better.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I don't really know, I'm not a UX designer, but I've seen that kind of thing on other mobile sites. It might be to accommodate narrower phone screens where the text in the search box might not fit. I assume it's a mobile-responsive thing since it switches at the same window width where the layout goes from normal horizontal to a mobile-style vertical

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Not sure about the other site but when I'm looking for dupe target answer I hop over to google and use: `search_terms "tag name1" "tag_nameN" site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Like Nathan said, add `site:` to your search term, like `site:stackoverflow.com` or `site:meta.stackoverflow.com`. The search narrows then to this site, but isn't 100% exclusive in any case. For example `site:meta.stackoverflow.com` still finds stuff on meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Looks like the break point for this is at ~820 px wide? That's what I'm seeing when I test it.

Comment: @Tom I very often want to search by _tag_, not just by site. Using the tag name as a word finds far too many false positives.

Comment: @Catija The cutoff is between 816px and 817px, at least on my system. It's the same cutoff as when the right-hand sidebar moves to the bottom.

Comment: Can't speak to the responsive breakpoints and the hiding of the search box in general, but we should at least fix the shortcut.

Comment: @CodyGray resize the window, make is smaller and you'll see the search box disappearing.

Comment: @Shadow Oh, I see. Yes, it's the same responsive theme I see on a phone. It's understandable for extremely narrow window widths; I can't say I have a problem with it. The shortcut "s" still works for me, even when the search bar is hidden and needs to be toggled by clicking on the magnifying glass icon. The bigger bug with the narrow viewports is that there's a *horizontal scroll bar* appearing in my icon buffet. (Moderator problems, perhaps?)

Comment: @CodyGray The keyboard shortcut works now. It didn't work yesterday. The inert space where a search bar should be is still there. I don't have a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed up the shortcut - turns out it's been broken for a good couple years, heh. The search bar hiding behaviour at narrow widths is by design, though.

Comment: Hiding the search bar is by design? Why???

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Can't speak to the specific thinking there cause I wasn't a part of the design process, but rearranging or hiding elements on differently sized screens is fairly common as far as I know, so it doesn't strike me as a particularly strange move.