# How can I always show the search bar at a medium window width?

Tags: support, search, user-interface, top-bar

My preferred window width is wide enough to have plenty of space between the left-hand icons and the right-hand icons, but [too narrow to have the search bar displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337679/search-has-become-much-harder-to-find-on-narrow-windows/337737#337737).

[image: screenshot]

How can I cause it to be always displayed, as it was until 2019-11-06? Preferably through a site feature but for whatever reason it's hidden by design; if not with a CSS tweak (installable with Stylish or the like); if not with a JavaScript tweak (installable through Tampermonkey or the like).

Comment: Could there be scripts that click the scripts which click the search bar or change the flag (looks like a bool which records the state of the search bar) at the time of resize? But it hides the site name, which I use to go to home page.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU6QS.png