# Tiny navigation buttons and tags on responsive mobile

Tags: support, bug, responsive-design

I know it will be hard for you to tell on desktop because the resolution is so high, but the clickable text in the upper left, the icons on the upper right, and the navigation buttons at the bottom are all tiny. I have to squint to read the tags, I can't reasonably tap any navigation button except for Next without zooming, and selecting the achievements dialog, etc. is all very difficult. It seems to me that this would not be terribly difficult to change, so I am posting this feature request. I'm using a relatively large Samsung phone (Note 8), so I can imagine it would be worse on smaller phones. [image]

Edit: I see from posted images that the responsive design on other phones looks nothing like mine. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the high resolution  where it thinks it is bigger than it is, or it's picking the wrong sizes because it's a tiny bit over some size threshold, in which case this would be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the mobile site, it's the desktop site.

You probably ticked the "Desktop site" checkbox in your browser:

[image: desktop site option]

Untick it, and you'll get a view fitting for mobile device:

[image: responsive site on mobile]

Comment: The mobile site is being phased out. This is the desktop site with the responsive design, which is what they say to use.

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: I don't have the link here, but they said they don't want to maintain two different UIs, and they recommended everyone use the responsive desktop site. Maybe I misunderstood, but that's what I saw.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the responsive site on mobile. You also might have tapped the "disable responsiveness" link in the footer by mistake. All in all, the responsive design exists and looking good on mobile devices already.

Comment: @Matt this applies to pages without responsive design yet, e.g. profile page, review, etc. In such pages, they're more usable with the desktop theme and not mobile theme.

Comment: Maybe my phone is over some size threshold where the responsiveness uses smaller elements. I checked and the responsiveness is definitely on, and the page you are showing looks more like my image than yours.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908) is the recommendation: We haven't fully optimized this for mobile devices, but click the "full site" option in the footer and you will get the responsive design on your phone. If for some reason you need access to the non-responsive version, we have a temporary feature for turning that on. Just click "Disable Responsive" option in the footer. This is a temporary feature that will go away once all the pages/features have been made responsive. The mobile optimized view will also remain in place until we finish making all the changes.

Comment: @MattSamuel It can be a little confusing because your phone's browser Settings lets you choose "Desktop version" or "Mobile version" independently of the page's "Mobile" and "full site" settings, so that gives you 4 different combinations. And then there's the "Enable responsiveness" / "Disable responsiveness" thing if "full site" has been selected.

Comment: @PM I see, selecting full site works.