# Something happened to my Chrome on mobile, and now Stack Overflow looks weird

Tags: support, mobile-web, mobile-chrome

Something happened to my Chrome on mobile (my phone was in my pocket, so maybe something got pressed), and now Stack Overflow looks weird.

What happened?

This is how it should look (this screenshot is from Chrome DevTools on desktop, using Samsung S5 option):

[image: How the website should look like]

And this is how it actually looks on my mobile (note that this is the standard view, not Desktop Site view):

[image: How it currently looks like on my mobile]

Comment: The full site / responsive design offers more functionality then the mobile version, FWIW. Also you could have clicked the "Request desktop site" button in the chrome menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tiny navigation buttons and tags on responsive mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346677/tiny-navigation-buttons-and-tags-on-responsive-mobile)

Comment: @mindstormsboi, no, the accepted answer in your linked post refers to Desktop Site being pressed, which is not the case here.

Comment: @mindstormsboi, I disagree. Turning Chrome's Desktop Site on and off doesn't help if StackOverflow's Mobile is pressed. Marking it as a duplicate is misleading, IMO.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I agree with the OP here, the duplicate target is about making the responsive theme look better, by changing a setting related to browser viewport. But the OP doesn't want to use the responsive theme, they want the mobile theme.

Comment: @HeyJude I hate to be the bearer of bad news but the weird Stack Overflow view you see is slated to be the only view available. Comments from Stack Overflow staff indicated they the mobile theme will soon be abandoned in favor of the responsive theme (so they can just focus on one front-end code base instead of two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have accidentally clicked on the "Full site" option which is available in the footer. To go back to mobile UI, scroll to the footer, find "Mobile" keyword and click on it.